# Why does firebug add <tbody> to <table>?

Tags: html, dom, firebug

I viewed the html source code, there is no `<tbody>`, but when viewed via firebug in the HTML tab, `<tbody>` appears. Any idea why?

Comment: (From @baptx): The weird thing is that creating a table without tbody using javascript createElement/appendChild will not add tbody but using innerHTML will do it. Why?

I've asked question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053572/no-automated-tbody-with-createelement-appendchild

Comment: This annoyed me *so much* when I was trying to compare my HTML parser's output to Firefox's HTML.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do browsers insert tbody element into table elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/938083/why-do-browsers-insert-tbody-element-into-table-elements)

Answer (score 20):

To summarize the excellent explanations given in the answers and comments by bobince, Kieron, Alohci and others:

1. Firebug just displays the DOM of the parsed page. Due to complicated HTML parsing rules, the DOM will "differ" (in some sense) from the source HTML.
2. In this case the `TBODY` element in the DOM is added by the HTML parser. Note that this weird parsing is limited to text/html documents and in XHTML the DOM corresponds closely to the source XML.

   - This behavior was specified in [HTML 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.1). The content model (allowed children) for `table` is `(CAPTION?, (COL*|COLGROUP*), THEAD?, TFOOT?, TBODY+)` -- `tr`s are only allowed in `tbody`! The spec says that `tbody`'s start tag is optional, which is supposed to mean that if the HTML parser encounters `tr` directly inside a `table` it inserts the `tbody` start tag omitted by the author.
   - To make matters more clear HTML 5 defines [very detailed parsing rules, in particular for this case](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/tokenization.html#parsing-main-intable): "When the insertion mode is "in table", tokens must be handled as follows: [...] A start tag whose tag name is one of: "td", "th", "tr" -> Act as if a start tag token with the tag name "tbody" had been seen, then reprocess the current token."

Answer (score 6):

Its not firebug, but firefox which does that. This is the way tables are supposed to be written with `<TBODY>` separate from meta data like `<COLGROUP>` Firefox simply inserts the `<TBODY>` tags when it finds them missing.

Comment: Is not Firefox, but Gecko :P

Comment: As for "why": Tables are supposed to have a `TBODY`, so Firefox' inner workings *want one to be there*. If you're not specifying it explicitly, it'll create it on its own, because it *wants one to be there*. Even if you're fine eating off the floor, you're placed at a table, because the waiter *wants a table to be there*. ;o)

Comment: @deceze, that's Firefox deciding that. The W3C standard says no such ting - tbody is optional unless you have a thead or tfoot.

Comment: @paxdiabolo: This can quickly slide into fine semantics, but: The standard **requires** the use of `TBODY`, **except for** when it's obvious that the only data in the table *is* the `TBODY` (paraphrased, as per your own comment on Kierons answer). That sounds like quite a strong encouragement to me and IMHO may be summarized with "is supposed to be there".

Comment: If the standard says it doesn't have to be there, it doesn't have to be there. Period. What people or browsers infer is irrelevant. The statement that tables are "supposed to be written with <TBODY>" is clearly incorrect. The standard says it's optional.

Comment: Obviously the standard can be read both ways. Fact is the *element* exists and *should* be used, but its *declaration can be skipped* if there's no ambiguity. *Internally* the browser just always assumes it's there because it makes implementing it easier. If by "it doesn't have to be there" you mean "its *explicit declaration* can be skipped", then I agree. The *element* though should always implicitly be there, and that's what you're looking at in Firebug. Don't confuse the markup with the interpreted result.

Comment: The "optional" part is tricky since it depends on the interpretation. You're erring on the side of *skip if not needed*, but the technical easier choice for the browser is *imply if absent*. A Standard™® open to interpretation?! Oh noes, stop the presses! ;o)

Comment: Great back on forth on standards interpretation. Similar to the perennial: Must <TPAIN> always to be wrapped by <AUTOTUNE>? ;)

Answer (score 4):

Firefox adds them, because the [standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.1) says so.

`TABLE` is not actually allowed to contain `TR` elements directly, they must be contained in `THEAD`, `TFOOT` or `TBODY`. But for simplicity and backwards compatibility, the start tag of `TBODY` may be omitted "when the table contains only one table body and no table head or foot sections"; in which case the element is inferred by the browser.

Comment: While not the most humorous or witty, this answer is the _correct_ one.

Comment: This is *not* the correct answer at all. If you're going to link to the standard and then comment on it, you might want to make sure your comment is right. The *standard* states: "TBODY start tag optional, end tag optional" and "The TBODY start tag is always required except when the table contains only one table body and no table head or foot sections. The TBODY end tag may always be safely omitted".

Comment: That is what “start tag optional” *means*. You can omit the start tag, but an HTML parser must still imply the element is there. The content model of `table` is `(CAPTION?, (COL*|COLGROUP*), THEAD?, TFOOT?, TBODY+)`; note `tr` is *not* in that list. It's like when you forget `<body>`, the parser will imply it as soon as you use an element like `<div>` that must be in body.

Comment: Note that this case is different for XHTML 1.0, because the weird SGML “start tag optional” feature does not exist in XML (thankfully). In this case the content model includes `(tbody+|tr+)`: you may use tbodies or bare trs but you can't mix them. In served-as-XML parsing mode, Firefox should not add the implied `tbody` element.

Comment: @bobince, whether the parser implies it or not, the *tag* is optional. The question asked why the tag had appeared.

Comment: @paxdiablo, right. But then the answer is that firebug doesn't depict *tag*s, it depicts *element*s. The tag is optional, the element is not.  (The question now, doesn't use the word "tag" or "element", but it's been edited, so maybe it did originally.)

Answer (score 1):

It's not added by firebug, it's added by Firefox. Firebug gives you what the actual dom looks like. If you browse through the various dom elements you'll notice Firefox has added some of it's own style elements as well.

Answer (score 0):

A.19. Explicit  Elements

DO use explicit tbody elements within tables.

Rationale: While the content model of the table element permits the tbody element to be skipped, in HTML 4 this element is implicit. HTML 4 user agents will silently add this element, thus potentially confusing scripts or style sheets.

Source : http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/NOTE-xhtml-media-types-20090116/#compatGuidelines