# Too long xpath with DOMXpath query/evaluate return nothing

Tags: php, xpath, domxpath

I am using PHP to retrieve content for a given URL and XPATH.
I use DOMDocument / DOMXPath (with query or evaluate).

For small xpath, I obtain correct result, but for longer xpath, it does not work. (And this xpath seems to be good (I obtained them with Xpather (firefox plugin) and re-test them with YQL).

Do you have any advice on this curious trouble ?

Example of code:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$myXMLString = file_get_contents('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097230/too-long-xpath-with-domxpath-query-evaluate-return-nothing');
@$doc->loadHTML($myXMLString); //@ to suppress warnings 
                               //(good for not ending markup)
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$fullPath ="/html/body/small/path"; //it works
//$fullPath = "/html/body/full/path/with/lot/of/markup";//does not works
$entries = $xpath->query($fullPath);
//or ->evalutate($fullPath) (same behaviour)
//$entries return DOMNodeList (empty for a long path query, 
//                             correct for a small path query)
```

I test with attribute restriction, but is seems to not change (with small xpath it works, with longer it do not works more)

Example :
for this current page:

```
$fullPath = "/html
              /body
               /div[4]
                /div[@id='content']
                 /div[@id='question-header']
                  /h1
                   /a";//works (retrieve the question title)
$fullPath = "/html
              /body
               /div[4]
                /div[@id='content']
                 /div[@id='mainbar']
                  /div[@id='question']
                   /table
                    /tbody
                     /tr[2]
                      /td[2]
                       /div[@id='comments-4097230']
                        /table
                         /tbody
                          /tr[@id='comment-4408626']
                           /td[2]
                            /div
                             /a"; //does'nt work 
                                  //(should retrieve 'gaby' from comment)
```

---

Edit:

I test with SimpleXML lib, and I have exactly the same behavior (good result for small query, nothing for long query).

---

Edit 2:

I also cut the longest xpath by deleting some first element and it works.
BTW I really do not understand why a full correct xpath does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's go through this step by step:

**Step 1: replicating the error.**

After verifying that the XPath will indeed not return a result, I wrote a little script to see how deep the XPath will go before it breaks

```
foreach (explode('/', $fullPath) as $segment) {
    $xpath .= trim($segment);
    echo '-------------------------------------------', PHP_EOL,
         'Trying: ', $xpath, PHP_EOL,
         '-------------------------------------------', PHP_EOL;
    echo $xp->evaluate("string($xpath)"), PHP_EOL;
    $xpath .= '/';
}
```

The last thing it will return a result for is

```
/html/body/div[4]/div[@id='content']/div[@id='mainbar']/div[@id='question']/table
```

---

**Step 2: checking the markup**

So I checked the markup returned by `DOMDocument::saveHTML()` to see what it looks like and there was no `<tbody>` *(reformatted for readability)*:

```
<div id="question">
    <div class="everyonelovesstackoverflow" id="adzerk1"></div>
        <table>
            <tr><td class="votecell">
```

I then checked this very page to see if it was DOM throwing it away or if it really does not exist. It wasn't there. Apparently, Firebug inserts it, which would explain why you got the result with XPather (but not why you got it with YQL):

[image: Screenshot showing page source and apparently bugged Firebug view]

**Step 3: proofchecking and conclusion**

I removed the `<tbody>` from the XPath and reran the script. No problems. Returns "Gaby".

While I suspected a bug in Firebug first, Alejandro commented this would happen in IE's DeveloperTools, too. I then suspected this to be added by JavaScript but could not verify that. After some more research Alejandro pointed me to [Why does firebug add `<tbody>` to `<table>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678494/why-does-firebug-add-tbody-to-table) - it's actually neither Firebug nor JavaScript though, but the browser's themselves.

So to modify my conclusion:

Dont trust markup you see rendered in the browser, because it may be modified by the browser or other technologies. DOM will only download what is is served directly. If you run into similar issues again, you now know how to approach it though.

---

**Some additional sidenotes**

Unless you need to modify the markup before feeding it to DOM, you do not have to use `file_get_contents()` to load the content. You can use DOM's `loadHTMLFile()`:

```
$dom->loadHTMLFile('http://www.example.com/foo.htm');
```

Also, the proper way to suppress errors is to tell [libxml](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.libxml.php) to use it's internal error handler. But instead of handling the errors, you simply clear them. This will only affect errors relating to libxml, e.g. parsing errors (as opposed to all PHP errors):

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);
libxml_clear_errors();
```

Finally, xPath queries can be done in relation to a context node. So while the long XPath is efficient in terms of lookup time, you could simply use `getElementById()` to get the deepest known node and then use an XPath against it.

In other words:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile('http://www.example.com/foo.htm');
libxml_clear_errors();
echo $xp->evaluate(
    'string(td[2]/div/a)', 
    $dom->getElementById('comment-4408626'));
```

will return "Gaby" as well.

Comment: Sorry, my post was not enough precise. I expect to return a DOMNodeList with a node (which contains gaby). (and thx for advice about libxml)

Comment: I saw the yql class but I prefer a fast and smaller way if possible (mean DOM or Simple xml lib usage but not external service)

Comment: @AurelienB since your other question suggests you are using Zend Studio, please try the following: download the markup and save it to a file. Open the file with the XML perspective in Zend Studio. If it's invalid, you might have to correct it first. Then use the XPath evaluator on the lower left to test if it finds your nodes.

Comment: @Gordon: +1 Very good answer. Also IE adds the `tbody`. I've also checked in Developer Tools Bar the first time.

Comment: @Alejandro thanks. And also thanks for checking with IE. It's not a Firebug bug then. I am bit stumped about the cause. See my update.

Comment: @Gordon: I think this is DOM mandatory. When the browser builds the DOM, some block elements that **must** be are added. I don't remeber the complete list. Maybe I should re check the HTML DOM specs...

Comment: @Alejandro does that mean it's happening in the browser's rendering engine? The browsers add it by themselves? I am pretty sure TBODY is optional though.

Comment: @Gordon: Yes. And [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678494/why-does-firebug-add-tbody-to-table) is the SO community own answer.

Comment: @Alejandro Ah, nice find. Thanks. I'll add it to the answer.