# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, html, dom

I just started to use [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net).

Now I'm trying to extract all elements surrounded with a `<b>`-tag inclduing `</b>` from an exsiting HTML document. This works fine with

```
foreach($html->find('b') as $q)
    echo $q;
```

How can I achieve to show up only elements surrounded with the `<b>`,`</b>`-tags followed by a `<span class="marked">`?

Update:
I've used firebug to get the css path for the elements. Now it looks like this:

```
foreach ($html->find('html body div#wrapper table.desc tbody tr td div span.marked') as $x)
    foreach ($x->find('html body div#wrapper table.desc tbody tr td table.split tbody tr td b') as $d)
        echo $d;
```

But it won't work... Any Ideas?

Update:

To clarify my question here a sample tr of the document with starting table and ending table tags.

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="desc">
    <tr>
        <th width="25%" scope="col"><div align="center">1</div></th>
        <th width="50" scope="col"><div align="center">2</div></th>
        <th width="10%" scope="col"><div align="center">3</div></th>
        <th width="15%" scope="col"><div align="center">4</div></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" bgcolor="#E9E9E9"><div style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold; margin-top: 2px"> 1 </div></td>
        <td>
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="split">  <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b> element to extract</b></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="split">  <tr>
                                <td width="15px" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td width="15px" valign="top">  
                                    <div style="background-color:green ;color:#FFFFFF; text-align:center;padding-bottom: 1px">
                                        1
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    abed
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="15px" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td width="15px" valign="top">  
                                    <div style="background-color:green ;color:#FFFFFF; text-align:center;padding-bottom: 1px">
                                        2
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    ddee
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="15px" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td width="15px" valign="top">  
                                    <div style="background-color:green ;color:#FFFFFF; text-align:center;padding-bottom: 1px">
                                        3
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    xdef
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="15px" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td width="15px" valign="top">
                                    <div style="background-color:green ;color:#FFFFFF; text-align:center;padding-bottom: 1px">
                                        4
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    abbcc
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="15px" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td width="15px" valign="top">  
                                    <div style="background-color:green ;color:#FFFFFF; text-align:center;padding-bottom: 1px">
                                        5
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    ab
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="15px" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td width="15px" valign="top">  
                                    <div style="background-color:green ;color:#FFFFFF; text-align:center;padding-bottom: 1px">
                                        6
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    e1
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td valign="top"><div style="text-align: center"> <span class="marked">marked</span> </div></td>
        <td valign="top"><div style="text-align: center">  </div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you mean `<b><elements/></b><span class="marked">` or `<b><elements/><span class="marked"></b>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following [CSS selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/)

```
b > span.marked
```

That would return the span though, so you probably have to do `$e->parent()` to get to the b element.

Also see [Best Methods to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662) for alternatives to SimpleHtmlDom

---

**Edit after update:**

[Your browser will modify the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678494/why-does-firebug-add-tbody-to-table). [If you look at your markup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097230/too-long-xpath-with-domxpath-query-evaluate-return-nothing), you will see that there is no tbody elements. Yet Firebug gives you

```
html body div#wrapper table.desc tbody tr td div span.marked'
html body div#wrapper table.desc tbody tr td table.split tbody tr td b'
```

Also, your question does not match the queries. You asked how to find

> elements surrounded with the `<b>,</b>`-tags followed by a `<span class="marked">`

That can be read to either mean

```
<b><span class="marked">foo</span></b>
```

or

```
<b><element>foo</element></b><span class="marked">foo</span>
```

For that first use the [child combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators) I have shown earlier. For the second, use the [adjacent sibling combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators)

```
b + span.marked
```

to get the span and then use `$e->prev_sibling()` to return the previous sibling of element (or null if not found).

However, in your shown markup, there is neither nor. There is only a DIV with a SPAN child having the marked class

```
<div style="text-align: center"> <span class="marked">marked</span>
```

If that is what you want to match, it's the child combinator again. Of course, you have to change the b then to a div.

Comment: @Eray I dont know up to what level SimpleHtmlDom implements them though. And tbh, I dont see why I would need them (or SimpleHtmlDom) when I can use DOM and XPath :)

Comment: FTR, simplehtmldom doesn't support sibling selectors, but [some alternatives do.](http://scraperblog.blogspot.com/2012/11/choosing-php-html-parser.html)

Answer (score -1):

More simple is from manual:

```
foreach($html->find('b') as $q)
    echo $q->plaintext;
```