# XPATH how to extract one td at a time from a tbody in HTML using HTML agility pack

Tags: html, html-agility-pack, xpath

I am trying to parse the table from the URL (Google finance) below

```
http://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=BOM:533278
```

I am trying to extract only the **close** values in the **close** column. But when i try with the XPATH

```
hd.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//td[@class='rgt']")
```

I am getting all the nodes of having attribute as class and value of attribute as rgt in one **Node.innerText** itself.

I need the values one by one, not all at the same time. I must be doing something silly here. Thank you.

Actual XPath found using Firebug is a  follows

```
/html/body/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]
     /div[2]/div/form/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[5]
```

But some how after the form tag...HTMLagility pack is returning null node. Never thought this would take so long to implement.

Comment: This is a **FAQ: browsers add mandatory elements to DOM** (as `head` and `tbody`). Your input source doesn't have any `tbody` element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using **Firebug** or any **Firefox** extension (like **XPather**) to obtain the `XPath` of the elements you need to parse, you might need to remove the `tbody` tags from the XPath.

Take a look at the following answer here on SO: [Why does firebug add <tbody> to <table>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678494/why-does-firebug-add-tbody-to-table)

If you're using **HtmlAgilityPack**, the `XPath` returned by **Firebug** or by any other tool related with **Firefox** may differ, because the **HTML source you're parsing can be different from the HTML source in Firefox**.

Sometimes might be useful to open the same page in **Internet Explorer 8** and using *Developer Tools (F12)* do the same you're doing with Firebug, or if not, use another tool like **HAP Explorer** that can be downloaded from the [HtmlAgilityPack page](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com)

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do it. Here is one solution, which is based on the Data td (the one withe the 'lm' class):

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
... load the doc ...

foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@class='lm']/../td[5]"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("node=" + node.InnerText);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

XPath for the first cell in Close column is `//div[@id='prices']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[5]` and for the second one it's `//div[@id='prices']/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[5]` and so on.

Comment: HtmlNode node = hd.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='prices']/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[5]"); - This is not working...i am still getting a null reference