# Using YQL and XPath to get data from HTML

Tags: html, xpath, yql

I've been playing around with YQL to try and understand it better as it seems like a pretty neat service but I have to admit Im quite the newbie when it comes it.  I've worked through some of the tutorials and examples and do understand it to a degree.  What I decided to do next was try and pull statistics from a website to display the league stats on a potential team site to see if it would work.

My YQL query was

```
select * from html
where url="http://www.nwjhl.com/leagues/standingsTotals.cfm?leagueID=15654&clientID=4594"
```

which returned some results, but obviously I dont need the entire contents, Im just trying to pull the standings.  I have managed to display the results on a local page but when I try to narrow down the results to just the team standings I get no results returned in the tree.  Im assuming it has to do with my xpath

```
select * from html
where url="http://www.nwjhl.com/leagues/standingsTotals.cfm?leagueID=15654&clientID=4594"
and xpath="/html/body/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]"
```

Being new I dont know if this is possible, just wondering if someone can steer me on the right track or knows of a good tutorial for this case.

Comment: The problem is the xpath - beware when pulling xpath from firebug/firefox because it cleans up tables. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678494/why-does-firebug-add-tbody-to-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be what you want:

```
SELECT * FROM html 
WHERE url="http://www.nwjhl.com/leagues/standingsTotals.cfm?leagueID=15654&clientID=4594" 
AND xpath="//tr[@class='boxscores_tables1'] | //tr[@class='boxscores_tables2']"
```