# No automated tbody with createElement/appendChild?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, firebug

Creating a table without tbody using javascript createElement/appendChild will not add tbody in Firebug but using innerHTML will do it. Why? Should we add the tbody manually?

Comment: I promote you add the tbody manually so you can use `table.tBodies`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using DOM creation methods, it must assume that you want the structure the way you created it.

If you want to ensure the same structure in different browsers, then yes you should always add it manually, even when JavaScript is parsing the HTML. Don't rely on the browser to insert it for you, because browsers may not behave the same in that respect.

---

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/JYd7L/) you can run in Firefox.

It starts off with this ***invalid*** markup.

```
<p>
    <div>original</div>
</p>
```

The `<div>` gets kicked out of the `<p>` when the HTML is parsed, leaving it rendered like this...

```
<p>‌</p>
<div>original</div>
<p></p>
```

But if we create an identical structure with DOM methods, Firefox doesn't do any corrections.

```
var p = document.createElement('p');

p.appendChild(document.createElement('div'))
    .appendChild(document.createTextNode('new'));

document.body.appendChild(p);
```

So the resulting DOM is now this...

```
<p>‌</p>
<div>original</div>
<p></p>

<p>
    <div>new</div>
</p>
```

So you can see that even in the case of a completely invalid structure, it doesn't make the corrections you'd see when it parses HTML.

Ultimately, what you should do is not rely on common browser tweaks or corrections, because there's no guarantee that they will be the same between browsers.

Use well-structured and valid HTML, and you'll avoid problems.

Comment: Thanks for the tips and example! It was weird for me, if DOM creation methods displays the structure the way you created it, an html table created manually should respect the way you create it too, without correction or the other way around, everything corrected.

Comment: @baptx: When you use HTML, you aren't really creating a DOM structure manually. You're creating it via *markup*, which must be parsed and interpreted into the DOM structure. I'm sure it's that interpretation that leads to the browser corrections. When you use DOM methods to build a DOM structure, there's no interpretation taking place. It's just the developer explicitly saying put this node into that one, and so the methods do what you tell it.

Comment: ...I'd imagine the *DOCTYPE* only plays a role in the interpretation of the *markup*, whereas the methods don't try to enforce a *DOCTYPE*.

Answer (score 0):

Because the start and end **tags** for the tbody element are optional. You bypass tag insertion by manipulating DOM nodes directly.

> Should we add the tbody manually?

That's somewhat subjective.

Comment: thanks, it's optional but the standard is not respected depending the way you use this nodes