# Firefox: tag attributes badly reordered after html parse

Tags: html, parsing, firefox, firebug

HTML code:

```
<input id="txtSizeBeforeValue" type="text" size="5" value="blabla">
<input id="txtValueBeforeSize" type="text" value="blabla" size="5">
```

HTML parsed code:

```
<input id="txtSizeBeforeValue" type="text" value="blabla" size="5">
<input id="txtValueBeforeSize" type="text" size="5" value="blabla">
```

Here you can see there is an issue with Firefox HTML parser, tag attributes are badly reordered with every HTML tag like input text/button, textarea, canvas...
Even if you write tag attributes like it is reordered, it is reordered again.
The problem is visible in Firebug and the HTML analyse developer tool of Firefox so it can't be a Firebug issue.
No problem with Google Chrome since the HTML parser doesn't reorder tag attributes.

Do you have this issue with Firefox too? On every platform?

Comment: Why should the order matter? I don't think the DOM standard specifies an explicit order for attribute nodes. From the spec: *`Attr` objects inherit the `Node` interface, but since they are not actually child nodes of the element they describe, the DOM does not consider them part of the document tree. Thus, the `Node` attributes `parentNode`, `previousSibling`, and `nextSibling` have a `null` value for `Attr` objects.* Given the methods to access attributes, an order is not needed anyways.

Comment: Why does Firefox reorder if it doesn't matter?

Comment: What are you doing that depends on the order of attributes? :)

Comment: Ok but my question was why Firefox parser cares about attributes order if it may be in any order. Chrome and other browsers doesn't change attibutes order.

Comment: Order matters when I'm trying to figure out which of several templates are being used with a quick look at html output. In firebug, I saw an `a` tag where the `href="#"` was the last attribute, and was confused when none of the templates I was looking at had it that way. I used Google Chrome view source to see what the output HTML looked like (I don't see that option in Firefox), and found out that Firebug was reordering the tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML spec states that "They may appear in any order."

here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.2

This is not a bug!

However you can create your own tool...

Comment: I've recently learned that the browser is making changes to the code when parsing html if something is missing like the <tbody> of a table, or wrong like <div> in <p> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053572/no-automated-tbody-with-createelement-appendchild Here I don't understand why Firefox will reorder tag attributes if it doesn't matter

Comment: Its like a list of properties of an object... doesnt matter the one that you declare first... they all live there. The parser outputs according to is own implementation (and that is NOT a bug)

Comment: Thanks, I'll remove the bug report, so Firefox wants it like that, it may appear in any order so the parser just ignores the order attributes have been added, strange choice. This thread will be helpful for users who will not understand why it is reordered.

Comment: @baptx: You have to think about it like this: As the order does not matter, the parser will not keep track of it, which probably makes the implementation easier, and just adds them e.g. to a set or hash map. To recreate the HTML, the system iterates over the internal data structure, but the order in which the attributes are stored there could be different than how it was written in the HTML.

Comment: The correct spec reference is http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-end.html#serializing-html-fragments

Answer (score 5):

You should blame the DOM for the reordering instead of blaming the parser. (I wrote the HTML parser in Firefox.)

In Firefox, different attributes are stored in different representations internally (particularly attributes that are treated as legacy presentational hints for CSS purposes). When you see attributes reordered, it means you have attributes belonging into different kinds of internal storage buckets on one element.

You'll find that the order of attributes you can read from IE's DOM also often isn't the same as the source order.

This is OK. The spec just requires the order to be stable, so if you read innerHTML twice without changing the attributes in between, you should get the same serialization twice.

> While the exact order of attributes is UA-defined, and may depend on factors such as the order that the attributes were given in the original markup, the sort order must be stable, such that consecutive invocations of this algorithm serialize an element's attributes in the same order.

http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-end.html#serializing-html-fragments

Answer (score 0):

The order of attributes doesn't matter as long as their values are assigned correctly