# HTML agility pack QuerySelector returns null

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack, fizzler

I'm using `Fizzler` for `Html Agility Pack`. This is my selector which works fine width jquery when I test it in firebug:

```
$('table.adsh>tbody:nth-child(1)>tr:nth-child(4) table tr:nth-child(1)>td:nth-child(2)')
```

But this line of code returns null in C# code:

```
var item = page.QuerySelector("table.adsh>tbody:nth-child(1)>tr:nth-child(4) table tr:nth-child(1)>td:nth-child(2)");
```

item is always null. Is there any thing wrong with my selector?

Any help is appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem. I printed out the `page.QuerySelector("table.adsh").InnerHtml;` and saw that it does not include any `tbody` tag. But when I `Inspect Element` the page in Chrome or FireFox the table includes `tbody` tag. The reson is that the original Html code does not include `tbody` and when I `Inspect Element` the table the browser adds `tbody` to the inspected code. In the page source I can see the original html.

Read more here: [Why does firebug add <tbody> to <table>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678494/why-does-firebug-add-tbody-to-table).

So I just removed `tbody` from my selector.