# Unable to find a button wrapping elements containing specific text for Selenium testing

Tags: java, css, selenium-webdriver

Given the following Html:

```
<button type="button"><b><em><u>Next</u></em></b></button>
```

In the page source I have more than one button. I have only option to find this element with text **Next**. I tried following methods but without success:

1. `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button>b>em>u[text()='Next']"))`
2. `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button>b>em>u[.='Next']"))`
3. `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button>b>em>u.contains('Next')"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be the case that the button has whitespace or other characters, I would switch to an `xpath` selector.

**Selecting the `u` element**

This xpath will select the `u` element:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button/b/em/u[contains(., 'Next')]"))
```

**Selecting the button**

To select the `button` containing the above `u` element, e.g. so that the button can be clicked:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[b/em/u[contains(., 'Next')]]"))
```

[Xsl fiddle of this here](http://xsltransform.net/gWmuiKd)

**Element not Found?**

As an aside, and in general, when looking at HTML to determine `css` or `xpath` selectors for `Se`, ensure that you are looking at the final rendered version of Html, and *not* just the original Html served from the web server - client side `javascript` may have modified the html significantly after loading, and also note that if the served html was not well formed, that [browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1678494/314291) can also [change html](https://stackoverflow.com/q/938083/314291). In Chrome, I use the `Developer tools` : `Elements` pane to view html.

Comment: StuartLC, I am getting error. he xpath expression '//button[b/em/u[contains(., 'Next')]]' cannot be evaluated or does notresult in a WebElement

Comment: At a guess there may be more than one button with the word `Next` on it (possibly hidden?). `driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//button[b/em/u[contains(., 'Next')]])[1]"));` should find just the first.

Comment: @virendrachaudhary Glad you found the issue - care to share? Might help future users :)

Comment: Thank you so much Stuart, following solution worked for me. driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button/b/em/u[contains(., 'Next')]"))

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning an ID to the button and then map the functionality to the button ID rather than button text like this:
`<button id ="btn1" type=button">`

Comment: in page source I have more than one element with same id, like cancel button and Next button are having same id.

Answer (score 0):

You are combining xpath selector syntax in your css selector. Try this in stead:

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button/b/em/u[text()='Next']"))`

or

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//u[text()='Next']"))`.

If you do wish to use a css selector, remove the `text()` part like so:

`driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button>b>em>u"))`

Comment: @BackSlash haha, I guess I should have tried it first then. Reverted!

Answer (score 0):

Below xpath should find 1st occurrence of "Next" button:

```
//button[text()='Next'][1]
```

If you want to get 2nd occurrence:

```
//button[text()='Next'][2]
```