# HTML scraping td content via XPath yields no data

Tags: xpath, scrapy, extract

I'm trying to extract some data from my college website for a project. This is my code. But item's fields contain no data.

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders.init import InitSpider
from scrapy.http import Request, FormRequest
import scrapy
from vasavi.items import VasaviItem

class MySpider(InitSpider):
    name = 'myspider'
    allowed_domains = ['domainsite']
    login_page = 'domainsite/index.aspx'
    start_urls = ['domainsite/My_Info.aspx']


    def init_request(self):
        return Request(url=self.login_page, callback=self.login)

    def login(self, response):
        """Generate a login request."""
        return FormRequest.from_response(response,
                    formdata={'txtLoginID': 'srichakra', 'txtPWD': '12345'},
                    callback=self.check_login_response)

    def check_login_response(self, response):

        if "SRI CHAKRA GOUD" in response.body:
            self.log("Successfully logged in. Let's start crawling!")
            # Now the crawling can begin..
        return self.initialized()

    def parse(self, response):
        print "Parsing"
        item = VasaviItem()
        ur = response.url
        print ur
        item['rollno'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="divStudInfo"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/text()').extract()
        item['name'] = response.css('#divStudInfo > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(2)::text').extract()
        item['Marks'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="divStudySummary"]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[9]/a/text()').extract()
        yield item
```

I was not allowed to post more than 2 urls here so I replaced all http://www.domain.com with domainsite

Output:

```
2015-01-03 18:45:06+0530 [myspider] INFO: Spider opened
2015-01-03 18:45:06+0530 [myspider] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2015-01-03 18:45:06+0530 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2015-01-03 18:45:06+0530 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 127.0.0.1:6080
2015-01-03 18:45:07+0530 [myspider] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET domainsite> (referer: None)
2015-01-03 18:45:09+0530 [myspider] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET domainsite/My_Info.aspx> from <POST domainsite/index.aspx>
2015-01-03 18:45:15+0530 [myspider] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET domainsite/My_Info.aspx> (referer: domainsite/index.aspx)
2015-01-03 18:45:15+0530 [myspider] DEBUG: Successfully logged in. Let's start crawling!
2015-01-03 18:45:21+0530 [myspider] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET domainsite/My_Info.aspx>(referer: domainsite/My_Info.aspx)
Parsing
domainsite/My_Info.aspx
2015-01-03 18:45:21+0530 [myspider] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 domainsite/My_Info.aspx>
        {'rollno': [], 'Marks': [], 'name': []}
2015-01-03 18:45:21+0530 [myspider] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2015-01-03 18:45:21+0530 [myspider] INFO: Stored json feed (1 items) in: vce.json
2015-01-03 18:45:21+0530 [myspider] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
        {'downloader/request_bytes': 1370,
         'downloader/request_count': 4,
         'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 3,
         'downloader/request_method_count/POST': 1,
         'downloader/response_bytes': 92491,
         'downloader/response_count': 4,
         'downloader/response_status_count/200': 3,
         'downloader/response_status_count/302': 1,
         'finish_reason': 'finished',
         'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 3, 13, 15, 21, 528000),
         'item_scraped_count': 1,
         'log_count/DEBUG': 8,
         'log_count/INFO': 8,
         'request_depth_max': 2,
         'response_received_count': 3,
         'scheduler/dequeued': 4,
         'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 4,
         'scheduler/enqueued': 4,
         'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 4,
         'start_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 3, 13, 15, 6, 518000)}
2015-01-03 18:45:21+0530 [myspider] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: This can't be debugged properly without seeing an example of the data you're retrieving from the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other commenters have noted, you really need to show the HTML input. If I had to guess though, I'd say `tbody` is not really present on the page - see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678494/why-does-firebug-add-tbody-to-table) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938083/why-do-browsers-insert-tbody-element-into-table-elements). `tbody` is present in the two path expression you show and also in the CSS.

To test this hypothesis, skip the `tbody` element in the expressions:

```
item['rollno'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="divStudInfo"]/table//tr[2]/td[1]/text()').extract()
```