# Parsing html page with lxml in python

Tags: python, xpath, html-parsing

i want to parse this Xpath query with lxml in python.

```
.//*[@id='content_top']/article/div/table/tbody/tr[5]/td/p/text()
```

I checked the xpath query in Firepath (the firebug extension for xpath),and it works,but my python code show me nothing.
Here's the source.

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get("http://www.scienzeetecnologie.uniparthenope.it/avvisi.html")
tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
avvisi = tree.xpath(".//*[@id='content_top']/article/div/table/tbody/tr[5]/td/p/text()")
print(avvisi)
```

The output is a `"[]"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no actual `<tbody>` element in the source html, its just an element in the DOM added by the HTML parser.

The firebug actually displays the DOM (and I am guessing firepath , which is a firebug extension works on this DOM (rather than the source html)).

For a more detailed explanation on `<tbody>` and why firebug displays it , check the answers to the SO question - [Why does firebug add <tbody> to <table>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678494/why-does-firebug-add-tbody-to-table) or this question - [Why do browsers insert tbody element into table elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938083/why-do-browsers-insert-tbody-element-into-table-elements)

---

In your case, removing the `<tbody>` from the xpath, would make it work , Example -

```
avvisi = tree.xpath(".//*[@id='content_top']/article/div/table/tr[5]/td/p/text()")
```

Comment: THANKS MAN YOU MADE MY DAY! :)
But why in the list ouput i have this strange chars? like \xa0 or similar? There is a way to avoid printing them?

Comment: Print each element on the list separately, when you are printing the list as such, you are getting the `repr()` output of the strings.

Comment: Something like - `for i in avvisi:
    print(i)`

Comment: Glad I could be helpful.