# beautifulsoup - unable to pick up tables (outside of iframe)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a table off the html pic linked below.

The table I am looking for is in the `tbody` that I've highlighted in blue, however, when I use `Beautifulsoup` to scrape this html document, I can only get information up until `('div', 'class': 'sic_localNav')`. Somehow, `Beautifulsoup` does not pick up all the information,(and the table) within the `div class`. - I have drawn an arrow to denote where this `div class` is.

```
a = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
b = a.find('div', attrs={'class': 'sic_localNav'})
print(b)

<div class="sic_localNav">
 <ul class="sic_section {default_type: 'insider_latest', default_market: 'sgx'}" id="nav_l3">
  <li class="nav_l3_tabs {type: 'insider_latest'}">
   <h3>
    Latest Insider Trades
   </h3>
  </li>
  <li class="nav_l3_tabs {type: 'insider_significant_sales'}">
   <h3>
    Significant Sales
   </h3>
  </li>
  <li class="nav_l3_tabs {type: 'insider_significant_purchases'}">
   <h3>
    Significant Purchases
   </h3>
  </li>
  <li class="nav_l3_tabs {type: 'insider_search'}">
   <h3>
    Search
   </h3>
  </li>
 </ul>
 <img alt="loading..." class="sic_icon_loadingLarge" height="32" id="sic_insider_loading_indicator" src="/images/icon_loadingLarge.gif" style="display: none;" width="32"/>
 <div class="sic_innerContainer" id="sic_insider">
 </div>
</div>
```

Any thoughts on why `Beautifulsoup` is not picking up the `tbody`? I've also checked, this `tbody` is not within an `iframe` or anything like that.

Any thoughts?

[image]

Sorry that the image is slightly blurry. It is not that your eyes are tired..

Comment: Maybe these are [added by Firefox/Firebug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678494/why-does-firebug-add-tbody-to-table)?

Comment: But I'm using Chrome. Not Firefox/Firebug

Comment: Are you sure you're not using something like angular to dynamically populate the section?

Comment: Nope. What is angular? I've not used before.. :/

Comment: Usually tbody  is a browser generated tag. If you show us the url maybe i could take a look

Comment: Hmm, I don't think I can show you the url? because I have to login to get to that page and get the information. So I was using `requests` and `Beautifulsoup` to login and extract the information.

Comment: Perhaps this tag is loaded after js is executed. Checkout this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049520/web-scraping-javascript-page-with-python