# nokogiri returns blank given correct xpath

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

run the following, and its supposed to return the company name. The xpath works in firefox, and it returns the company name. however in nokogiri, this isn't happening, it jsut returns empty string!

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

 doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.careerbuilder.com/JobSeeker/Jobs/JobDetails.aspx?IPath=QHK
CV&ff=21&APath=2.21.0.0.0&job_did=J3G71D73BM9HCK1M84Z&cbRecursionCnt=1&cbsid=6d2aee1515ed404b8306d1a583592cd4-314600403-JQ-5'))
companyname = doc.xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/form[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[2]/td[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[1]/div[1]/div[2]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[2]").to_s

puts companyname
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your xpath is not correct :)

You should omit the `tbody` part, this is generated by the browser but *not* by nokogiri!

```
doc.xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/form[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tr[2]/td[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tr[1]/td[1]/div[1]/div[2]/table[1]/tr[1]/td[2]").to_s
```

NB: *Also you xpath will be more stable against changes of the HTML page if you use any `class` or `id` attributes to selected nodes, rather than the full path. For example you could use*

```
doc.xpath("//div[@class='job_desc'][1]/table[1]/tr[1]/td[2]")
```

*or even simple just use a css selector*

```
doc.css("div.job_desc td")[1]
```

Comment: any idea why browser adds tbody ?

Comment: The HTML standard defines that browsers must do so, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/938083/why-do-browsers-insert-tbody-element-into-table-elements