# How to groups table rows in html to manipulate them with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I have an html table with many rows.  I'm currently grouping several rows inside a div (I know this is ugly) and then show or hide the divs to show or hide the rows inside it.  Is there a standard way to do this. Something like rowgroup or multiple tbody instead of this ugly div grouping?

Comment: Ray's answer is correct. I'm surprised you haven't tried it yet, since you mention it in your question.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Use `<tbody>` tags for this

Comment: Can you have multiple tbodys to group the rows.  I've though that you had one thead, one tbody, and one tfoot per table.

Comment: Multiple tbdodys are fine. You are correct that only one thead and tfoot are allowed.

Comment: `<tbody>` tags do not support everything that other tags do such as padding and margin, for these situations, @matpol has the better solution, but this is the best solution to the question from the OP unless under these special circumstances.

Comment: Beware of automatic `tbody` addition http://stackoverflow.com/questions/938083/why-do-browsers-insert-tbody-element-into-table-elements and add all those `tbody` elements explicitly on the HTML.

Comment: what about nested tbody for the purpose of grouping rows above a tbody and those within?

Answer (score 8):

Give them a class name that is consistent then you can do:

```
$('table td.classname')
```

To get the ones you want.

Comment: In the old days retrieving elements by class name could be unacceptably slow on some browsers. Today it's usually built into the DOM.

Comment: shouldn't this be `tr.classname` ?