# Is it necessary to have <tbody> in every table?

Tags: xhtml, w3c, semantic-markup, w3c-validation

According to standards, is it necessary to have `<tbody>` in every table?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it required to use thead, tbody and tfoot tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29111522/is-it-required-to-use-thead-tbody-and-tfoot-tags)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Only if you define `thead` and `tfoot`. It is mostly used when the table has multiple bodies of content. If the data in the table is easily understood to be the `tbody` then you can safely omit it.

Comment: and is `<th>` allowed to use inside `tbody tr`?

Comment: Semantically, if you have a header to your table with `<th>`, then you should use `<thead>` though it is not *required* that you do so. If you are using them as the header for a column, then you should not put them in the `tbody`, but if they are headers for a row, they can be.

Comment: @Aaron Harun - I just noticed firefox always add `tbody` to table even if we are not using `<thead>`, `<tfoot>`, and multiple `<tbodies>`

Comment: @metal-gear-solid - Not just Firefox, in the text/html serialization all browsers will infer the missing tbody tags. Not in the application/xhtml+xml serialization though, of course.

Comment: @metal-gear-solid - Whether it's good or not is a matter of opinion and depends on your personal development philosophy. All I can provide are facts. It's unnecessary, but if you want to serve your web page with both mime types, then explicitly using tbody means that your DOM can have the same structure regardless of the serialization. This can make your scripting simpler.

Comment: Don't really know since when, but most browsers add `tbody` automatically. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67335357/css-properties-padding-via-a-rule-doesnt-work-whereas-same-css-inline-applie led me here by the way (I asked ask it first)... With child selector I can have side-effects not to put it then : e.g. `table > tr` would not match. This is also mentioned here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938083/why-do-browsers-insert-tbody-element-into-table-elements.

Answer (score 24):

Quoting the [HTML 4 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#edef-TBODY): "The TBODY start tag is always required except when the table contains only one table body and no table head or foot sections. The TBODY end tag may always be safely omitted."

So, you must have a `<tbody>` tag if you have a `<thead>` *or* `<tfoot>`

See also: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody)

Answer (score 19):

For the small fraction of your users still using IE7, you MUST add encapsulate your tr's in a tbody tag if you're building a table with the DOM methods!

This will work in all major browsers:

```
var table = document.createElement('table');
var tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
var tr = document.createElement('tr');
tbody.appendChild(tr);
table.appendChild(tbody);
```

This will NOT work in IE7:

```
var table = document.createElement('table');
var tr = document.createElement('tr');
table.appendChild(tr);
```

A quick blog post of mine on building tables: 
http://blog.svidgen.com/2012/05/building-tables-in-ie7-with-javascript.html

<sup>It may be notable that I no longer make the effort to support IE7 on my own projects. The IE<=7 share is likely negligible for most sites at this point.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Dumb Guy gave [an answer for HTML4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3078121/1729441) (**yes**). Arwym gives [an answer for HTML5 to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45240537/1729441) (**no**):

> The [tabular data spec for
> HTML5](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-tr-element)
> does not require them:
>
> > *Contexts in which this element (`tr`) can be used:*
> >
> > - As a child of a `thead` element.
> > - As a child of a `tbody` element.
> > - As a child of a `tfoot` element.
> > - **As a child of a `table` element**, after any `caption`, `colgroup`, and `thead` elements, **but only if there are no `tbody`
> >   elements that are children of the table element**.
>
> Even though I believe it is a good practice to section your rows
> within `thead`, `tbody` and `tfoot` tags as it makes the table's rows
> easier to identify.
>
> In the end, the browser will always add at least the `tbody` for you.

Answer (score 1):

According to [HTML 3.2 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/SPSD-html32-20180315/#table) (`table` wasn't in HTML 2 spec) `table` element doesn't have `tbody`, `thead`, `tfoot` (they are HTML 4 things), only optional `caption` and list of `tr` / `th`.

While you might think what's the hell you are talking about HTML 3.2 dated 1997 in 2021 consider email clients with primitive or outdated HTML engines, `tbody` makes no sense in here.

Answer (score -5):

Most browsers are forgiving but even so I add the pair in all tables that I use now.   Even trivial tables.   Especially now that I'm using CSS more and more to decorate those tables.

All that being said I have old tables that still work fine on the newest browsers.   I'm learning the hard way but taking the few extra Micro seconds to add the optional tags here and there ends up saving you money/time in the long run.

Dave

Comment: How can adding tbody tags to a table save you any money/time?