# why tbody tag appears in inspect elements?

Tags: html

in this page: [enter link description here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_tbody.asp)

there isn't any `<tbody>` in the HTML under this table:

```
<table class="reference notranslate"> 
<tr>
<th align="left" width="20%">Attribute</th>
<th align="left" width="20%">Value</th>
<th align="left" width="60%">Description</th>
</tr>
...
```

but when I use inspect elements in Google Chrome or Mozilla Firefox there is a tbody element in this table over the first `<tr>`.
[image]

why this happens?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because `<tbody>` is an expected element inside of a `<table>` Chrome puts it there because it belongs. It'll happen just the same if you open an html file with nothing inside of it. Chrome and (most other browsers) will automatically but the `<html>, <head> and <body>` tags. Check this [question out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078099/is-it-necessary-to-have-tbody-in-every-table) for more information.