# HTML table height and width not reflecting CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I specified my HTML table to have a `min-height: 50%` and `min-width: 60%`, but as you can see my table size does not reflect this. It seems to have sized to be just big enough to contain its child element. Can someone explain why this behavior occurs when I expect my table to the specified height and width?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

#wrapper {
  border: 3px solid black;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.table {
  border: 3px solid red;
  min-height: 50%;
  min-width: 60%;
  margin: 10% auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>age</th>
            <th>grade</th>
            <th>percentage</th>
            <th>passing</th>
            <th>notes</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS display: table min-height not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790222/css-display-table-min-height-not-working)

Comment: no, because I tried using {height: 50%; width: 60%} as well and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Setting `display: block;` on the table-class should do the trick. Although you might want to then set max values for the width and height as well (or just use width and height).

Comment: I think this is not a good way to use <table />

Answer (score 0):

Just add this

```
<tbody>
    <tr></tr>
</tbody>
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

#wrapper {
    border: 3px solid black;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}

.table {
    border: 3px solid red;
    min-height: 50%;
    min-width: 60%;
    margin: 10% auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>name</th>
                    <th>age</th>
                    <th>grade</th>
                    <th>percentage</th>
                    <th>passing</th>
                    <th>notes</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

It's interesting, when you only have `thead` in the table, it doesn't apply the styles correctly. If you remove the `thead` tag it works or if you add an empty `tr` inside `tbody`.

So,
[if you use thead you must use tbody](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078099/is-it-necessary-to-have-tbody-in-every-table#:%7E:text=Quoting%20the%20HTML%204%20spec,may%20always%20be%20safely%20omitted.%22)