# css properties (padding) via a rule doesn't work, whereas same css inline-applied does

Tags: html, css

I have the following code and cannot figure out why it doesn't work :

```css
table {
    border: 1px solid black;
    }

table.whole > tr > td {
    padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<!-- doesn't work via css rule -->
<table class="whole">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>abcd</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<hr>
<!-- works inline -->
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="padding:20px 0 20px 0">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>abcd</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

May I misunderstand how the child selector `>` works or is there some kind of limitation here, or a bug ?...

Comment: you have the tbody element added by the browser `table.whole > tbody > tr > td`

Comment: Yes I saw that, but I didn't suspect the rule to be applied _after_ ! Indeed by adding `> tbody` it works, Thx (I'll add `<tbody>` in the html too)

Comment: try not to use the `>` selector. whenever there is a change is HTML, your styling breaks.. which should not be. Better is to add a css class to the td element.

Comment: @SudiptoRoy ok, here it's a wrapper in a template for an internal email that will be read in Outlook clients... Otherwise I wouldn't even have used tables !! By bumping into the problem, I thought of using a class indeed, but also wanted to understand the problem I had... But yes, you're definitely right it's more risky!

Answer (score 3):

If you inspect your code in the Chrome devtools, you will see that the browser has automatically inserted the required [`<tbody>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody) element between the `<table />` and rows for you.  Because of this, the `<tr />` is no longer the direct descendent of the `<table />`.  So the issue is that your HTML is malformed/not adhering to the spec.  If you add the `<tbody />` element and rewrite your CSS accordingly, it will work just fine:

```css
table {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

table.whole > tbody > tr > td {
    padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<!-- doesn't work via css rule -->
<table class="whole">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>abcd</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Indeed, I will always add `<tbody>` now in my html, thx :-)

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, there must be a `<tbody>` element between `<table>` and `<tr>` elements. Chrome is being nice, so it helpfully inserts it for you. However, that breaks your CSS, because now `<tbody>` is the child of `<table>`, and not `<tr>`.

### Solution:

Include a `<tbody>` (otherwise it would be invalid and confusing), and change your CSS code to:

```
table.whole > tbody > tr > td {
    padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
}
```

```css
table {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
table.whole > tbody /* ...and put it here. */ > tr > td {
    padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<table class="whole">
    <tbody> <!-- include a <tbody> element... -->
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>abcd</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

*Note: the inline styles work because they don't have any random selector errors because they're placed right in the `<tbody>` element.*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078099/is-it-necessary-to-have-tbody-in-every-table states that it is not mandatory in all cases... But I'll use it in the future if needed, or avoid `>` selector in this case.

Comment: Yes, but Chrome puts it in for you, and you *should* use it, because otherwise you might get unexpected errors. And if you don't use the `>` selector, it might select the nested table.

Comment: yes, I mean _use a class instead_, not only _not use it_ ...