# CSS Issue in JQuery

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I tried to apply color to rows of a table using the following code. It doesn't work, but I don't understand why. Could someone explain why or point me in the right direction?

**HTML:**

```
<table id="tblSample" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="300px">
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$("#tblSample > tr").css("background-color", "gray");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing the elusive [`tbody` element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938083/why-do-browsers-insert-tbody-element-into-table-elements).

http://jsfiddle.net/m7HTt/

You can do this:

```
$("#tblSample > tbody > tr").css("background-color", "gray");
```

or this:

```
$("#tblSample tr").css("background-color", "gray");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to do alternating row colors you can do something as simple as this as well.

```
$("#tblSample tr:even").css("background-color", "gray");
```

Comment: Thanks Mike! yr solution also really helpful for me.i didn't know before we can apply alternate row color in this way.

Answer (score -1):

Try it

```
$("#tblSample  tr").css("background-color", "gray");
```

or

```
$("#tblSample tr td").css("background-color", "gray");
```