# Why doesn't table > tr > td work when using the child selector?

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-selectors

I can't really get why the following selector works as expected (i.e. get the `td`):

```
table tr td
```

but this one doesn't:

```
table > tr > td
```

The `td` is a descendant of `tr`, which in turn is a descendant of `table`, but they are also children of each other. Therefore, I thought that the `>` selector would work too.

I made two fiddles:

1. Child: http://jsfiddle.net/brLee/
2. Descendant: http://jsfiddle.net/brLee/1/

Why isn't the `>` selector working here?

Comment: IE 6-7 don't support > at all

Comment: Same thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125407/css-issue-in-jquery/5125413#5125413

Comment: @MadBender: IE7 supports `>` in standards mode.

Comment: @thirtydot: +1 to your answer.

Comment: @BoltClock: I started writing that comment before your (again) very rapid answer. It took me a while to find my answer, ended up searching for "elusive" :p You can have a +1 for 10 :)

Comment: @thirtydot: You're such a cool person.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

In HTML, browsers implicitly add a `tbody` element within which to contain the `tr` elements<sup>1</sup>, so in reality, `tr` is never a child of `table`.

Consequently, you have to do this instead:

```
table > tbody > tr > td
```

Of course, if you add a `tbody` element yourself, you use the same selector. The [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#the-tbody-element) explains when a `tbody` is added implicitly otherwise:

> ### Tag omission
>
> A `tbody` element's start tag may be omitted if the first thing inside the `tbody` element is a `tr` element, and if the element is not immediately preceded by a `tbody thead`, or `tfoot` element whose end tag has been omitted.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>This is not the case for XHTML documents that are properly served as `application/xhtml+xml`, however, [given its XML roots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7490364/why-do-browsers-still-inject-tbody-in-html5/7491956#7491956).</sub>

Comment: I wasn't aware of that at all. Your solution works just great.

Comment: @pimvdb: Not many people are - most just learn about `table`, `tr` and `td` when they start out. I didn't know about `tbody` myself until a couple of years ago (considering I first picked up HTML from Neopets...).

Comment: Note that <tbody> is optional in XHTML, and will *not* be added to the DOM (ref:http://javascript.about.com/od/hintsandtips/a/htmldom.htm). Safest option is to just use `table tr` in selectors.

Comment: @Mark Thomas: Good to know. Is it cross-browser? This fiddle with a doctype of XHTML 1.0 Strict does add a `tbody` element in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/9uL8s/.

Comment: @pimvdb Yes, it's cross-browser and safer. `table tr` allows for a `<tbody>` inbetween, but `table > tr` does not.

Comment: Note also that browsers still add `tbody` elements even when parsing and rendering as HTML5. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7490364/why-do-browsers-still-inject-tbody-in-html5).

Comment: @pimvdb: I'm late, but jsFiddle doesn't serve documents with XHTML doctypes as `application/xhtml+xml`, so it'll still be treated as HTML tag soup, hence the addition of `tbody`.

Comment: @MarkThomas - `table tr` without the child selector may be the safest option, but it will cause problems if you have nested tables. (not that I'm recommending nested tables! -shudder-)

Comment: @BoltClock does this automatic `tbody` addition applies also to `thead` and `tfoot`?

Comment: @Ozichukwu: No, because not every table has a thead and/or a tfoot, and browsers can't make assumptions as to whether the author meant to use them.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be more catholic than the pope :) here is what I did (because none of the above worked for me):

1) Create a css class, assign it to the  property of the GridView (eg:

```
<PagerStyle CssClass="pagerNoBorder" />
```

)

2) Define you css class just as the page numbers are rendered by your browser (inspect the element in the browser and look for all the child selectors!). In my case, this was the situation:

```
.pagerNoBorder > td > table > tbody > tr > td
    {
        border-width:0px !important;
        border-style:none;
    }
```

If you're going to say why border-width (+ !important) and border-style in the same time then read again the intro of my answer :) . Cheers and good day!