# css background change for tr

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to give good background effect to rows using this css

```
tr:hover td{background-color:#ddd; }
```

imagine a table inside a table,
naturally all td's inside,  also effected by this css. How can I prevent?

```
<table
    <tr
        <td -->color change is good
    <tr
        <td
            <table
                <tr
                    <td --> color change is bad
```

I tried using

```
form>table>tr:hover td still same
form>table>tr:hover>td not working at all
```

thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to style only your outer `td`s on hover.

```
form > table > tbody > tr:hover > td {
    background-color: #ddd;
}
```

Notice the `tbody` selector. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5568859/why-doesnt-table-tr-td-work/5568877#5568877) for why it's needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use a second selector:

```
tr:hover table td { background-color: black; } /*change to default*/
```