# Creating tables with jQuery without tbody

Tags: jquery

How do I create tables in jQuery without tbody being added to my code by jQuery? See http://jsfiddle.net/r7BFq/

```
$('table').html('<tr><td>A</td><td>B</td></tr>');
$('pre').text($('table').html());​
```

results in

```
<tbody><tr><td>A</td><td>B</td></tr></tbody>
```

I don't want that. I want:

```
<tr><td>A</td><td>B</td></tr>
```

Comment: It's not jQuery's fault :) he is a nice guy

Comment: Who's fault is it? How do I prevent it?

Comment: Just don't use a table then.. Add it to a div instead.. Coz the tbody is added by the browser by default .. http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/r7BFq/1/

Comment: Actually browser creates the `tbody` element not jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why Would you try to remove `tbody`. your browser is trying to add the part of valid html, you are missing. Is it not nice?

Comment: border-collapse wasn't working, I thought it was because of tbody being added. I did a border-collapse inline style. It works. So I agree with you that I should allow the browser to make my code HTML valid.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this demo please** http://jsfiddle.net/d8zVX/

*Quote* @undefined bruv: `Actually browser creates the tbody element not jQuery`

Further read this:

[Why do browsers still inject <tbody> in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7490364/why-do-browsers-still-inject-tbody-in-html5)

**Quote**

> For historical reasons, certain elements have extra restrictions
>   beyond even the restrictions given by their content model.
>
> A table element must not contain tr elements, even though these
>   elements are technically allowed inside table elements according to
>   the content models described in this specification. (If a tr element
>   is put inside a table in the markup, it will in fact imply a tbody
>   start tag before it.)

This will fit the need `:)`

**Code**

```
$('table').html('<tr><td>A</td><td>B</td></tr>');
var hulk = $('table').html().replace(/<\/?tbody>/g, '');;
$('pre').text(hulk);​
```

**Working Image**

[image]

Comment: @TimothyClemans in the pre tag it shows this `<tr><td>A</td><td>B</td></tr>` which is what you want right? rest browser will add the `tbody` back anyways. `:)` I am on mac air - Lion O/S - safari browser and cannot see `tbody` http://jsfiddle.net/d8zVX/ `:)`

Comment: @TimothyClemans hmmm see I have added working-image above now! no `tbody` atleast on `pre` tag.

Comment: yes but I want the code the browser is running to not have the tbody

Comment: @TimothyClemans Browser makes your table welformed by adding `tbody` read this as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678494/why-does-firebug-add-tbody-to-table **or** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7490364/why-do-browsers-still-inject-tbody-in-html5

Comment: thanks! wish google had showed me those stackoverflow questions when i was searching for javascript adding tbody, don't add tbody javascript, etc

Comment: @TimothyClemans `:)` Will complain to google, he sits next to me `:)` it must be cluster near you which is not readin mapreduce algo. :P

Answer (score 0):

This works perfect:

HTML:

```
<div id="table_sample"></div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$('#table_sample').html('<tr><td>A</td><td>B</td></tr>');
$('#table_sample').text($('#table_sample').html());
```

Comment: That wasn't part of the question/requirements. This code does exactly what was asked. I can understand if it doesn't fully work for you in the context of your whole code, but it is a correct answer to the question asked.

Comment: @Jesse You can't put a `tr` tag inside a `div` tag, it's not valid markup.