# CSS hover disable nested table

Tags: html, css, hover

I have a problem with CSS `:hover` class. How do I disable second table `:hover` class which is inside the second row.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bigboytr/yrZ8R/)

**HTML**

```
<table border="0" width="100%" id="product-table">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Title of the table</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="20%"><b>Text text</b></td>
    <td>someting about product</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>text text</b></td>
    <td>
        <table border="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr bgcolor="#ddd">
                <td colspan="6"><strong>Title of inside</strong></td>
            </tr>
            <tr bgcolor="#efefef">
                <td width="20%"><strong>No</strong></td>
                <td width="20%"><strong>Date</strong></td>
                <td width="20%"><strong>Define</strong></td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="hat_ekle">
            <tr>
                <td>123</td>
                <td>2013</td>
                <td>some text</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>234</td>
                <td>2013</td>
                <td>some text</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
#product-table tr:hover { background:#333; }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One method is to make the selector more restrictive:

```
#product-table > tbody > tr:hover { background:#333; }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yrZ8R/2/

`>` indicates that only the direct child should be matched.

See also:

- [CSS Selectors Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors)
- [Why are we using `<tbody>` in the selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7490364/why-do-browsers-still-inject-tbody-in-html5)?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.

```
.table-hover tbody tr:hover td table tr td {
    background-color: revert;
}
```