# getElementsByTagName("table") - getting td on curious way

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have this simple example

```
 <table border="1px">
  <tr> 
    <td> </td>
    <td> <input type="button" value="Click" onclick="insertText()"/> </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

I wanted to get the first td element of the (first) tr element, I tried:

```
var td = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0].children[0].children[0];
```

Because it's:

- `var td = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0]` for the table element itself
- `children[0]` for the tr element
- and `children[0]` again for the first td element

That's what I thought, but apparently this returns me the tr element and only adding another `.children[0]`got me the td element.

```
var td = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0].children[0].children[0].children[0];
```

Why is that, or what have I missed here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's because you're forgetting about the `<tbody>` element, which is automatically inserted into the DOM.

What your table really looks like:

```
<table border="1px">
  <tbody>
    <tr> 
      <td> </td>
      <td> <input type="button" value="Click" onclick="insertText()"/> </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Hence why you needed to dig down through three levels of children to target the `<td>` element you wanted.

***Side note:*** If you'd like to know more about why the `<tbody>` element is automatically injected into `<table>` elements if undeclared, [see this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7490364/1586880).

Comment: @stack_temp Of course :) I'll try to add a little bit more explanation when I get home from work in a min

Comment: I don't mess w/ tables I thought they were old school, I just use embedded divs.