# Browser sometimes adds in <tbody>

Tags: javascript, php, html, checkbox

I saw a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678494/why-does-firebug-add-tbody-to-table), but was not sure of a solution, and the circumstances are slightly different, so I thought I would ask it again.

I have a page that has both PHP and JavaScript. The PHP retrieves info from a database, and creates a checkbox using it. This checkbox is wrapped inside a table for correct formatting. There is a button on the page, and when it is pressed, JavaScript creates a new checkbox, with the same formatting as the one created in PHP. I have some code that allows me to see if any of the checkboxes are pressed:

```
alert(selectedCheckBoxWrapper.firstChild.firstChild.firstChild.checked);
```

As you can see the code attempts to look inside the `<table>` wrapper and find out if the checkbox is checked or not. The problem that I am having is, the checkbox created in PHP is different to the cone created in JavaScript.

**PHP checkbox:**

```
<table style="visibility: visible; position: absolute; top: 104px; left: 177px; width: 150px; height: 25px;" id="obj1" border="0" name="btn_177_1_test1">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td valign="middle" width="1">
<input type="checkbox" id="obj1_child" disabled="">
</td>
<td valign="middle" style="font-size: 13px;">
<label for="obj1_child">test1</label>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**JavaScript checkbox:**

```
<table style="visibility: visible; position: absolute; top: 216px; left: 166px; width: 150px; height: 25px;" id="obj2" border="0" name="btn_177_1_test2" >
<tr>
<td valign="middle" width="1">
<input type="checkbox" id="obj2_child" disabled="">
</td>
<td valign="middle" style="font-size: 13px;">
<label for="obj2_child">test2</label>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The PHP checkbox has a `<tbody>` tag, while the JavaScript one does not. This messes up my code to see if it is checked or not, as if it tries to find a checkbox generated by PHP, it is unable to find the checkbox checked.

I have included the code that I use to create the checkboxes.

**PHP create code:**

```
echo "<table style=\"visibility: " . $part['visible'] . "; position: absolute; top: " . $part['top'] . "px; left: " . $part['left'] . "px; width: " . $part['width'] . "px; height: " . $part['height'] . "px;\" id='obj" . $part['part_id'] . "' border=0 name='btn_" . $part['stacks_id'] . "_" . $part['cards_id'] . "_" . $part['name'] . "'>
<tr>
<td valign='middle' width=1>
<input type='checkbox' id=\"obj" . $part['part_id'] . "_child\" " . $part['disabled'] . ">
</td>
<td valign=\"middle\" style=\"font-size: 13px;\">
<label for=\"obj" . $part['part_id'] . "_child\">" . $part['name'] . "</label>
</td>
</tr>
</table>";
```

**JavaScript create code:**

```
var newTableElement = document.createElement( "table" );
newTableElement.setAttribute('style', newElementStyle );
newTableElement.setAttribute('id', newElementID );
newTableElement.border = 0;
newTableElement.setAttribute('name', newElementName );
var newTableElementRow = document.createElement( "tr" );
newTableElement.appendChild( newTableElementRow );
var newTableElementCell1 = document.createElement( "td" );
newTableElementCell1.setAttribute("valign", "middle" );
newTableElementCell1.width = 1;
newTableElementRow.appendChild( newTableElementCell1 );
var newTableElementCell2 = document.createElement( "td" );
newTableElementCell2.setAttribute("valign", "middle" );
newTableElementCell2.style.fontFamily = "'Lucida Grande', Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;";
newTableElementCell2.style.fontSize = "13px";
newTableElementCell2Label = document.createElement( "label" );
newTableElementCell2Label.setAttribute('for', whatElement.getAttribute('id') + "_child" );
newTableElementCell2Label.innerHTML = innerContents;
newTableElementCell2.appendChild( newTableElementCell2Label );
newTableElementRow.appendChild( newTableElementCell2 );
var newElement = document.createElement( "input" );
newElement.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox' );
newElement.setAttribute('id', whatElement.getAttribute('id') + "_child" );
newTableElementCell1.appendChild( newElement );
```

The variables such as newelementStyle and innerContents just contain preset values.

Is there something wrong with my code? Or is there a way to tell the browser not to add in the `<tbody>` tags?

Comment: you can see an answer why tbody is required found in this stackoverflow post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7490364/why-do-browsers-still-inject-tbody-in-html5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating a `table` element with JavaScript, you need to insert the `tbody` element in order to match the structure of the `table` element as created by the HTML parser. The HTML *markup* need not have `tbody` *tags*, but the `tbody` *element* is there.

So you simply need to modify the JavaScript code so that after creating the `table` element, it creates a `tbody` element, makes it a child of the `table`, and later makes all `tr` elements children of the `tbody`, not the `table`.