# Is the insertion of <tbody> in HTML tables standard?

Tags: html, html-parsing, html-table, language-lawyer

In HTML, when parsing a `table` element with `tr` elements inside, a `tbody` is usually inserted:

[image: <tbody> is inserted inside <table> (http://jsfiddle.net/ed9msnfp/)]

```js
function log(el, ctx) {
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(el.tagName.toLowerCase()));
  var ul = document.createElement('ul');
  for(var i=0; i<el.children.length; ++i)
    log(el.children[i], ul);
  li.appendChild(ul);
  ctx.appendChild(li);
}
log(document.querySelector('table'), document.getElementById('dom-tree'));
```

```css
table {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2</td></tr>
</table>
The table is parsed as:
<ul id="dom-tree"></ul>
```

Is this behavior standard?

I couldn't find it described in [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html), but it makes sense, because the `insertRow` DOM method automatically creates `tbody` elements too:

> ***tr* = *table* . [`insertRow`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#dom-table-insertrow)( [ *index* ] )**
>
> Creates a `tr` element, along with a `tbody` if required, inserts them
>   into the table at the position given by the argument, and returns the
>   `tr`.

Comment: `tbody` is part of the standard HTML definition (see section 4.9.5 in th elink you gave for the spec), but its use is not required. It's so that rending engines can distinguish between heading and body (see `<thead>` as well).

Comment: @lurker Yes, I know `tbody` is not required (the content model of `table` allows `tr` without `tbody`). However, if you don't include it, most browsers will insert it. Can I rely on that?

Comment: @lurker you should post that as an answer

Comment: @lurker I have included a snippet which demonstrates that the `tbody` is **literally** inserted when the table is parsed into the DOM. That happens on Firefox, Chrome and IE8.

Comment: Ah thanks for the snippet. I see what you mean. To me, it's not literal unless it changes your HTML file. Other than that, it's still an "internal" rendering. ;) Semantic difference... :)

Comment: Here's a [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7490364/why-do-browsers-still-inject-tbody-in-html5). More directly, here's the HTML5 documentation ([The "In Table" Insertion Mode](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/syntax.html#parsing-main-intable)) that discusses this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's standard. It's described in [Parsing HTML documents](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#parsing) (instead of [Tabular data](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html)):

> If *node* is a [`table`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-table-element) element, then switch the [insertion mode](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#insertion-mode) to "[in table](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#parsing-main-intable)"
>
> [**8.2.5.4.9 The "in table" insertion mode**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#parsing-main-intable)
>
> When the user agent is to apply the rules for the "[in table](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#parsing-main-intable)"
> [insertion mode](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#insertion-mode), the user agent must handle the token as follows:
>
> - A start tag whose tag name is one of: "td", "th", "tr"
>
>   [Insert an HTML element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#insert-an-html-element) for a "tbody" start tag token with no
>   attributes, then switch the [insertion mode](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#insertion-mode) to "[in table
>   body](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#parsing-main-intbody)".