# Why Chrome adds tbody tag to each table row?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, mustache

I have two tables that fill up throw an event.

The stylesheet is made for that the even rows get painted white.

```
table {

border-collapse: collapse;
width: 100%;

}

td, th {
border: 1px solid #dddddd;
text-align: left;
padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

But due Chrome adds `tbody` tag to each `tr` tag it's doesn't work.

The first table fill up throw back-end:

```
var prueba = {};
    prueba = nuevaCadena[nuevaCadena.length - 1].replace(/<br>/g, "").split(",");
    prueba.venta = prueba[0];
    prueba.fecha = prueba[1];
    prueba.heladeria = prueba[2];

    //prueba.base.split(",");

    //if (myElem === null) {
    var contenido = document.getElementById("contenido");
    var tr2 = document.createElement("TR");


    if (contenido.getElementsByTagName("TH").length === 0)
    {
        contenido.appendChild(tr2);
        tr2.innerHTML += "<th>Heladeria</th>";
        tr2.innerHTML += "<th>Fecha</th>";
        tr2.innerHTML += "<th>ID</th>";

    } else {
       var template = "<tr><td>{{heladeria}}</td><td>{{fecha}}</td><td>{{venta}}</td></tr>";

        document.querySelector('#contenido').innerHTML +=       Mustache.render(template, prueba);

   }
```

And the second works perfectly. It's fill up throw the `select` tag  values.

```
var contenido = document.getElementById("contenido2");
var tr2 = document.createElement("TR");

var tr = document.createElement("TR");
if (contenido.getElementsByTagName("TH").length === 0)
{
contenido.appendChild(tr2);
tr2.innerHTML += "<th>Heladeria</th>";
tr2.innerHTML += "<th>Fecha</th>";
tr2.innerHTML += "<th>Sabor</th>";
tr2.innerHTML += "<th>Cantidad</th>";

}



contenido.appendChild(tr);

//var th = document.createElement("TD");
var option = ["heladerias", "sabores"];
var valor = document.getElementById("sabor_calorias");
var fecha = document.getElementById("fecha");


for (var i = 0; i <= 0; i++) {

var input = document.getElementById(option[i]).selectedIndex;
var input2 = document.getElementById(option[i]).options;

tr.innerHTML += "<td>" + input2[input].text + "</td>";
tr.innerHTML += "<td>" + fecha.value + "</td>";

for (var j = 1; j <= 1; j++) {

    input = document.getElementById(option[j]).selectedIndex;
    input2 = document.getElementById(option[j]).options;
    tr.innerHTML += "<td>" + input2[input].text + "</td>";
    tr.innerHTML += "<td>" + valor.value + "</td>";
    tr.innerHTML += "<input type='button' class='borrar' value='x'         onclick='deleted(this)'/>";

}


}
```

The results  are this:

This question didn't work for me [Why do browsers insert tbody element into table elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938083/why-do-browsers-insert-tbody-element-into-table-elements)  i use Mustache.

[image: Screenshot of Table]

[image: Screenshot of Chrome adding tbody]

Comment: What is the final HTML that chrome has?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWfWd.png is  in the link above "Chrome adding tbody"

Comment: @TOMAS ah ok, thanks. Just as a point - it's not considered good practice to include code as images/screenshots

Comment: @bitsoflogic No, that question doesn't solve the problem in any way it  just explained.. NO solutions...

Comment: Sorry, but that JavaScript code is irrelevant.  Show the final HTML as it goes over the wire, _not_ the parsed DOM as displayed in the browser.

Comment: @Svante  it is on the question have a look...

Comment: have you tried to start with  : `<table>  <tbody id="contenido2"></tbody></table>` instead `<table id="contenido2"> </table>` so tbody is already there

Comment: I have just done that a moment a go and it works. It seems to be that it is not posible to avoid  `tbody` using Mustache.

Answer (score 3):

When parsing the HTML syntax, the browser will insert a tbody tag, as explained in [Why do browsers still inject <tbody> in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7490364/why-do-browsers-still-inject-tbody-in-html5). By appending to the innerHTML each time, you're creating a new tbody each time. The HTML syntax can't represent a tr as a direct child of a table.

You could instead use

```
tr = table.insertRow()
tr.innerHTML='<td>foo<td>bar'
```

if you still wanted to write the row with innerHTML, or use `td = tr.insertCell()` as well.

Comment: Ok. but check the last table is create with inner and doesn' t have the same problem .. I try to add the `<td>` tag individuality  `tr.inner += "<td>{{heladeria}}</td>"`  and the problem is solved but Mustache doesn't fill the `{{}}`  tags

Answer (score 0):

The  tags that chrome add are not needed, and shouldn't affect your code.

If you keep getting the error you might want to try going through to make sure you don't have any missed-placed characters.

Comment: But they are affecting his code - they mess with `nth-child` in CSS

Comment: They shouldn't.

Comment: tbody:nth-child(even) will fix the css.