# CSS direct descendant ">" operator not working (and it's not IE6)?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to do something very simple - select the  tags which are direct descendants of a  tag.

The CSS I am using is as follows:

```
table.data > tr { background-color: red; }
```

My HTML looks like this:

```
<table class="data">
    <tr>
        ...
    </tr>
</table>
```

But no red background is forthcoming!  If I remove the ">" character from the CSS, it works!  I have tried this in Firefox, IE 8, Chrome and Safari, and all the browsers do exactly the same thing.

Hopefully someone can help me after so many frustrating hours! I know I am doing something extremely stupid, but I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't table > tr > td work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5568859/why-doesnt-table-tr-td-work)

Comment: maybe you don't need the > since tr is contingent on a table tag and a natural direct descendant of table syntax...? <table><tr><td>text</td></tr></table>

Comment: @Chris22 This only works if there are no nested tables inside.

Answer (score 25):

Most<sup>1</sup> browsers automatically insert a `tbody` element into a `table`, so the css should be:

```
table.data > tbody > tr { background-color: red; }
```

to account for that.

---

<sup>1</sup> I *think* that all browsers do this, but I don't have the capacity, or time, to check that assumption. If you're concerned that there might be some users with a browser that doesn't do this, you could offer both selectors in the css:

```
table.data > tr,
table.data > tbody > tr { background-color: red; }
```

Comment: @Jon Heh. I was thinking the same thing... :p

Comment: I was in the middle of a TF2 game when this popped up, so my close vote probably came too late. But your answer is pretty much correct anyway, so have an upvote!

Comment: @BoltClock: why. thank you kindly! :) Clearly I used the wrong search terms (which given the question is difficult in itself) when I looked for the duplicate(s). Oops...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried this, but it doesn't work either.  I looked at the HTML code from the browser (of course), and there is no <tbody> tag.  Man, this is weird...

Comment: @Flyingkiwi: 'view source' or from, for example, Firebug or Web Inspector? Could you post your table, and CSS, to [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: I am viewing the source directly from Firefox, not Firebug.  I understand that Firebug and Firefox can differ.  I will try writing a completely new, simple HTML page to isolate this issue.  Perhaps something else is interfering.

Comment: Browsers add the `<tbody>` to the DOM, not the HTML source. This is why you see that the HTML source is not modified at all - it really isn't.

Comment: OK. So I isolated the problem in a test file and it works perfectly. I don't know why my real code works now, but I can confirm that the tbody is definitely inserted (but not displayed in the source!), and is required in the HTML.

Comment: @DavidThomas WRT your assertion that the `tbody` may not _always_ be inserted auytomatically: you're right. If the file is XHTML, the browser doesn't insert a tbody. XML parsers don't do that kind of thing. So the proposed solution is good: it targets both HTML and XHTML files.