# Selecting specific tr element in a table (CSS)

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to select the 5% `tr`, but my css selector does not seem to work. I also have to write one for the 10% `tr`, which I expect will be simple after the 5% `tr` is solved. My selector seems to work down to `table`, but I cannot get it to select the second `tr`. What am I doing wrong?

**Code:**

```css
body > form > div > table > tr:nth-child(2) > td:first-child {
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<form method="post">
  <div>
    <table cellpadding="0" align="center" cellspacing="0" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
          &nbsp;
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 5%">
          5%
        </td>
        <td>
          <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="height: 100%; border-color: #e0e0e0;">
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width="10%" valign="top" style="height: 100%;">10%</td>

              <td valign="top" width="90%">
                My Content
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Give it a `class`. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_class.asp

Comment: You might find this question relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7510850/82548

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Target with following CSS:

```
tr[width="10%"]{

}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me and the solution I went with, though many of these solutions work.

Comment: @tarun713 I am glad it helped.

Answer (score 3):

If you do **NOT** want to change with your HTML markup, meaning adding classes (which would be easier to target the `TR` and `TD`) you can use [**`:nth-of-type`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type)

#### Snippet

```css
tr:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: red
}
table table tr:nth-of-type(2) td:first-of-type{
  background: lightblue
}
```

```html
<table cellpadding="0" align="center" cellspacing="0" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
          &nbsp;
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 5%">
          5%
        </td>
        <td>
          <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="height: 100%; border-color: #e0e0e0;">
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width="10%" valign="top" style="height: 100%;">10%</td>

              <td valign="top" width="90%">
                My Content
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: plus 1 from me ... no reason having 2 more or less identical answers :)

Comment: Got it, so I should not use the > characters. My Content is also colored in this solution, but I can use your example to write a more precise solution. Thank you. EDIT: My bad, I said tr in the original post when I should have said td. Fixed that - your solution is correct for my original question. Thank you.

Comment: So its correct for your original question and you mark another answer as accepted? care to explain?

Comment: Both answers worked for me. I have upvoted your answer.

Comment: Just FYI, If you remember to change that 5% to 6% or that 10% to 9%, the answer you have chosen won't work anymore unless you will change it, so its not so effective :)

Comment: Yup, understood. At this point we only have access to change what's in the content td. Everything else is system generated, and for the life the site we're generating, we can count on the system continuing to generate the explicit markup with 5%.

Answer (score 2):

Give it a class so you can select it directly, without having to specify the entire chain:

```
<tr class="my-tr">
     <td style="width: 5%">
     ....
</tr>
```

Then you can select it in css:

```
.my-tr {
    background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: Why use JS when this can be achieved with Pure CSS? and it is not even tagged as JS question :)

Comment: @dippas Correct, I wanted to show how to select in CSS. Have no idea why I continued with JS :)

Comment: Maybe the habit takeover you :)

Comment: Unfortunately, the html is system generated and I can only apply css after the HTML is generated! Thank you for the response though. I'll vote it up because for folks who do have access to the HTML, this is a valid answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use `nth-of-type` pseudo selectors. The nested table was tricky, I used `td > table` to find it. Your 1st target is `background: red` and 2nd target is `outline:2px solid yellow`

```css
table {
  outline: 3px dashed blue;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
table:first-of-type {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
/* 1st target acquired */
table:first-of-type tr:nth-of-type(2) td:first-of-type {
  background: red;
}
form > div {
  height: 50vh;
  width: 90vw;
  outline: 1px solid black;
}
td > table {
  outline: 1px solid lime;
}
/* 2nd target acquired */
td > table tr:nth-of-type(2) td:first-of-type {
  outline: 2px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>TestPage</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    /*body > form > div > table:first-of-type > tr:nth-child(2) > td:first-child { background-color:red };*/
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <form method="post">
    <div>
      <table cellpadding="0" align="center" cellspacing="0" border="0">
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3">
            &nbsp;
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="width: 5%">
            5%
          </td>
          <td>
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="height: 100%; border-color: #e0e0e0;">
              <tr>
                <td colspan="2"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td width="10%" valign="top" style="height: 100%;">10%</td>

                <td valign="top" width="90%">
                  My Content
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```