# Why does $('#table > tr') selector not match? (always return 0)

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

The html code:

```
<table id='table'>
    <tr>
        <td>..</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The js code with jquery:

```
var l1 = $('#table > tr').length;
var l2 = $('#table tr').length;
alert(l1+','+l2);​
```

The result:

```
 0,1
```

Why the first `#table > tr` get 0?

You can see a live demo from here: http://jsfiddle.net/Freewind/PmsFQ/

Comment: Please go the the *other* question and close it for this one if warranted (this question is written better and more to the point).

Comment: @pst: Done. It always makes me a little uneasy knowing the close description says "this is the same as *earlier* questions", but I think it's alright in this case.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because the direct children of a `<table>` can only be `<thead>`, `<tbody>`, or `<tfoot>` (or `<colgroup>` or `<caption>`, but those don't contain rows).

The browser's DOM will implicitly wrap stray `<tr>`s in a `<tbody>`. (for browsers that don't do this, jQuery fakes it instead)

You need to write `$('#table > tbody > tr')`.

Comment: The second sentence is true for HTML (as well as HTML5), but not XHTML. See [these](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5568877/106224) two [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7491956/106224).

Answer (score 3):

This is because browsers automatically insert the `<tbody>` element between your `<table>` and `<tr>`, such that the rows are no longer the direct children of your table.

Answer (score 2):

Your browser is adding a `tbody` element so `tr` is not the child of the table.

Comment: They will still be direct descendants of the table... Just not the children of it :-)

Comment: @Codemonkey That's what I meant by "_direct_ descendant." But yeah, child is better.

Comment: @Codemonkey: ["direct descendant" is the same as "child"...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3225905/106224)

Comment: @BoltClock Perhaps in programming, but in all the references I could find "direct descendant" just means following a straight path of lineage, e.g. I'm a direct descendant of my grandfather