# Extracting some portion of data using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a complete page coming in my success message and it is comingas complete html, inside it it has

```
<table><tr><td><font class="abc"><a></a> - these are multiple </font></td></tr></table>
```

now i am trying to get the paging contents based upon the find of jquery to get the inner contents of the font tag

trying like this:

```
$("#mydiv").find("table>tr>td>font").html();
```

but that does not seems to be working

***Thanks everyone for answers, To Update here #1***

**to make sure i get the element i need the text [pages] is written inisde te font tag, so want to have a check if the fonr has pages then extraxt whole content inside the font**

Thanks

Comment: Do the answers to this question address your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5568859/why-doesnt-table-tr-td-work-when-using-the-child-selector? Incidentally, the [`<font>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font) is deprecated, please consider using CSS instead.

Comment: You shouldn't be using the `font` tag. It's outdated(unsupported in HTML5) and is not meant to be used the way you are using it here.

Comment: I wrote a jQuery selector tester once upon a time that could come in useful here http://joefitter.github.io/selector-tester/#/

Comment: can i add a check like this: which returns me true and false: `var paging = $("#mydiv").find('table>tbody>tr>td>font:contains("Pages")');`

Answer (score 0):

You can find the font tag with class "abc" with the following-

```
$("#mydiv").find('.abc')
```

Now, to get the content of this tag, you can do-

```
$("#mydiv").find('.abc').html()
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not work, because the `<table>` Element is the root node for your snippet. Hence, `.find()` can't do its job, since it only searches child nodes.

```
.find("tr>td>font").html();
```

would work for that reason.

Answer (score 0):

After inserting in your html DOM your table has additional `tbody` inside your table, so your selector doesn't work.

So you can do it with another selector:

```
$("#mydiv").find("tbody > tr > td > font").html();
```

Comment: True, but the important part here is to drop the `table` selector.

Comment: If he inserts result of first query into div - then it will be ok. But we don't know exactly, so I've edited my selector

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
$("table").find(".abc").html();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the class to target the element, then slightly change the select:

```
$("#mydiv").find("table div>tr>td>font").html()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `<tbody>` tag, which the browser renders (to correct incorrect html). Also, the `<font>` tag is deprecated, so you may want to avoid using it.

Try this:

```
$("#myDiv").find("table > tbody > tr > td > font ").html();
```

See [**this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/a4yoz2ox/2/)