# Override first-child in CSS class with another class

Tags: html, css

In a web page we have a table nested within another table. In our CSS class `first-child` is used to give the first row a blue background. How can I prevent this blue background from being inherited by the nested table.

Also please note that I cannot alter the original styles.

Here is the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a0muwsk1/

The last CSS block, `.Main table table td`, was one attempt at overriding the first-child styling...It did not work.

And here is the same code from the fiddle page:

Html:

```
<table class="Main">
    <tr>
        <td>This</td>
        <td>is</td>
        <td>first</td>
        <td>child</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>Regular</td>
        <td>Row</td>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Nested</td>
                    <td>first</td>
                    <td>child</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Nested</td>
                    <td>Table</td>
                    <td>Row</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>        
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.Main table
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.Main tr:first-child td
{
    background-color: blue;
    text-align: center;
    border-width: 0px 0px 1px 1px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
}

.Main td
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial;
    color: black;
}

.Main table table td
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial;
    color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, but your attempt using

```
.Main table table td
```

refers to a **table inside a table inside a table**--one too many nesting levels. You meant to write:

```
.Main table td
```

However this rule will have lower specificity than the existing

```
.Main tr:first-child td
```

To avoid this problem, you can write it an a way parallel to the origin rule, including the `tr:first-child` part:

```
.Main table tr:first-child td
```

which will have greater specificity. See this specificity calculator: http://specificity.keegan.st/

This says in English

> **But** if the `td` is in the `tr:first-child` inside a `table` which is itself inside `.Main` (the top-level table), then do **not** apply the previous rule making it `blue`, instead, make it transparent or something else.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/torazaburo/a0muwsk1/6/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the direct child selector. `.element > .childElement`

So your CSS will look something like this

```
.Main > tbody > tr:first-child td
{
    background-color: blue;
    text-align: center;
    border-width: 0px 0px 1px 1px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
}
```

Here is the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a0muwsk1/3/

**Edit:**

I forgot about some table magic. Browsers implicitly add a `tbody` element to `table` elements. This answer explains more about the browser magic. [Why doesn't table > tr > td work when using the child selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5568859/why-doesnt-table-tr-td-work-when-using-the-child-selector)

Comment: The outer table should retain the first-child styling. It's first row should be blue.

Comment: Although, I could add another style for `<th>` and use that instead of first child `<td>`... No this will not work because it will affect all pages on the site.

Comment: @navig8tr I've corrected my answer. Tables like to behave very differently than your typical element.