# CSS selector for first TH after a caption in a table

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a `table` that I want to select the very first `TH` only if it contains a `caption`. I thought it might be something like this:

```css
.myTable caption + tr th:first-child
{
    /* stuff */
}
```

It's instead selecting nothing. Is this a bug in CSS or just my logic?

See my JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ukb13pdp/1/

```css
.objectTable th:first-child
{
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
}

.objectTable caption + tr th:first-child
{
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table class='objectTable'>
    <caption>Caption Table</caption>
    <tr>
        <th>A</th>
        <th>B</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br/><br/>
<span>No Caption Table</span>
<table class='objectTable'>
    <tr>
        <th>C</th>
        <th>D</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cause here is exactly the same as the one described in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5568859/why-doesnt-table-tr-td-work-when-using-the-child-selector) about the use of child selectors with `tr`. The problem is that `tr` elements are made children of an implicit `tbody` element, so what ends up being the sibling of the `caption` is that `tbody` and not the `tr`:

```
.myTable caption + tbody th:first-child
```

As an aside, if your `th` elements reside in a header row they should ideally be contained in a `thead` element and the data rows contained in explicit `tbody` element(s):

```
<table class=myTable>
  <caption>Table with header group</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Header<th>Header
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Row 1<td>Row 1
    <tr><td>Row 2<td>Row 2
</table>
```

And selected using

```
.myTable caption + thead th:first-child
```

Answer (score 1):

You're forgetting about the `<tbody>` element which wraps the `<tr>` element. Even though not specified in your (otherwise invalid) HTML, the `<tbody>` element is automatically implemented by the browser as a way of validating this, so instead of:

```
<caption>
<tr>
```

You end up with:

```
<caption>
<tbody>
    <tr>
```

As seen in this element inspector capture below:

[image: Element Inspector View]

To select the very first `<tr>` element after a `<caption>` element, you can instead use:

```css
caption + tbody tr:first-child {
    ...
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/ukb13pdp/3/).