# How do you style the topmost row in a table?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I thought I was reasonably versed in CSS, but this one has me stumped.

How do you target the topmost row of a table, if you don't know what the table structure is? My CSS file needs to be independent of however the HTML is structured.

So what is the selector I should use? If the table has a `thead`, then it's easy.

```
.theTable > thead > tr:first-child {..}
```

and if it only has one or more `tbody` elements, that's easy too.

```
.theTable > tbody:first-of-type > tr:first-child {..}
```

but if you don't know? How do you prevent ending up styling both the `thead` and the `tbody`?

For example, how do you make sure that in the following three tables, only the top row in each one gets the style?

```css
/* bad CSS */
table tr:first-of-type {background:tan;}
```

```html
<table>
 <thead><tr><th>nr</th><th>name</th></thead>
 <tbody><tr><td>1</td><td>one</td>
        <tr><td>2</td><td>two</td></tbody>
</table>
<hr>
<table>
 <tbody><tr><td>1</td><td>one</td>
        <tr><td>2</td><td>two</td></tbody>
</table>
<hr>
<table>
 <caption>names</caption>
 <tbody><tr><td>1</td><td>one</td>
        <tr><td>2</td><td>two</td></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `table tr:first-of-type`? Can you post some more complete examples of what isn't working, specifically the HTML?

Comment: @j08691 `first-of-type` means the first of this type IN ITS PARENT. So if a table has a thead and two tbodies, each of these three elements has a `first-of-type` tr. In elements that can contain only one certain type of children (like these), `first-of-type` means exactly the same as `first-child`.

Comment: And I can post some examples, but I'm afraid that the answers will only concentrate on those specific examples, without actually solving the problem.

Comment: I think you'd have to select the first tbody and thead and then reset styles on the tbody if it existed. Something like the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/41545694/616443

Comment: @j08691 Thanks for that link! I did search before posting, but apparently not good enough.

Comment: And one of the answers there helped me out exactly, so this one can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

As @j08691 said, could you not use `tr:first-of-type`?

**Edit**: This is super tricky due to the way CSS cascades, and the nesting specifically, but I think what your looking for is the following? (Though I think you'll need to override cases like the second table.

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

thead {
  border: 2px solid #f00;
}

tbody {
  border: 2px solid #0f0;
}

tfoot {
  border: 2px solid #00f;
}


/* Top most row regardless of table structure. */

table > tbody > tr:first-child {
  color: #f0f;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Savings</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>Sum</td>
      <td>$180</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>

<br/>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Foo</td>
    <td>ABC</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bar</td>
    <td>DEF</td>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Alex</td>
      <td>Lucy</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mira</td>
      <td>Dave</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br/>

<table>
  <caption>Table stuff...</caption>
  <tr>
    <td>Test 1</td>
    <td>Awesome</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Test 2</td>
    <td>Cool</td>
  </tr>

  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>Conclusion</td>
      <td>Erm what?</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't mention what happens when a table has both `thead` and `tbody` elements.