# color all tr element inside table if td is clicked using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I having table trying to color all tr element using jQuery when it called from any child td element. Here is my code.

```
<table>
  <tr style="color: rgb(31, 73, 125); background-color: #eaeaea;"><td style="padding-left: 5px;"><a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="download_excel(this,'BL8','ATR','AWFR')">ATR-ADM-BLCMA8-CHN18-03-01-D</a></td><td>14</td><td>0</td><td>56</td><td>56</td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td></tr>
  <tr style="color: rgb(31, 73, 125); background-color: #eaeaea;"><td style="padding-left: 5px;"><a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="download_excel(this,'BL8','ATR','AWFR')">ATR-ADM-BLCMA8-CHN18-03-01-D</a></td><td>14</td><td>0</td><td>56</td><td>56</td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td></tr>
  <tr style="color: rgb(31, 73, 125); background-color: #eaeaea;"><td style="padding-left: 5px;"><a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="download_excel(this,'BL8','ATR','AWFR')">ATR-ADM-BLCMA8-CHN18-03-01-D</a></td><td>14</td><td>0</td><td>56</td><td>56</td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td></tr>
</table>
<script>
  function download_excel(element,a,b,c){
    $(element).parents('table').children('tr').css("background-color", "#fbfbfb");
  }
</script>
```

Because I want to highlight the clicked one(already have code), rest I want to reset to previous background color.. that's y

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:- Use `find()` function instead of `children()` function.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
      <tr style="color: rgb(31, 73, 125); background-color: #eaeaea;"><td style="padding-left: 5px;"><a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="download_excel(this,'BL8','ATR','AWFR')">ATR-ADM-BLCMA8-CHN18-03-01-D</a></td><td>14</td><td>0</td><td>56</td><td>56</td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td></tr>
<tr style="color: rgb(31, 73, 125); background-color: #eaeaea;"><td style="padding-left: 5px;"><a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="download_excel(this,'BL8','ATR','AWFR')">ATR-ADM-BLCMA8-CHN18-03-01-D</a></td><td>14</td><td>0</td><td>56</td><td>56</td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td></tr>
<tr style="color: rgb(31, 73, 125); background-color: #eaeaea;"><td style="padding-left: 5px;"><a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="download_excel(this,'BL8','ATR','AWFR')">ATR-ADM-BLCMA8-CHN18-03-01-D</a></td><td>14</td><td>0</td><td>56</td><td>56</td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td></tr>
    </table>
    <script>
    function download_excel(element,a,b,c){
     $(element).parents('table').find('tr').css("background-color", "#fbfbfb");
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: it's doing for only one TR, i want to change for all the tr at one shot...thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try with [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements in the following way:

```js
function download_excel(element,a,b,c){
  $(element).parents('table').find('tr').css("background-color", "#fbfbfb");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr style="color: rgb(31, 73, 125); background-color: #eaeaea;"><td style="padding-left: 5px;"><a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="download_excel(this,'BL8','ATR','AWFR')">ATR-ADM-BLCMA8-CHN18-03-01-D</a></td><td>14</td><td>0</td><td>56</td><td>56</td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td></tr>
  <tr style="color: rgb(31, 73, 125); background-color: #eaeaea;"><td style="padding-left: 5px;"><a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="download_excel(this,'BL8','ATR','AWFR')">ATR-ADM-BLCMA8-CHN18-03-01-D</a></td><td>14</td><td>0</td><td>56</td><td>56</td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td></tr>
  <tr style="color: rgb(31, 73, 125); background-color: #eaeaea;"><td style="padding-left: 5px;"><a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="download_excel(this,'BL8','ATR','AWFR')">ATR-ADM-BLCMA8-CHN18-03-01-D</a></td><td>14</td><td>0</td><td>56</td><td>56</td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

While you've already accepted an answer for this question, I felt it worth pointing out some of the problems with your initial approach; while the `<tbody>` element is optional when writing HTML the browser, when constructing the DOM, will routinely create that element — if it doesn't already exist — and place the `<tr>` elements within it; therefore the line:

```
$(element).parents('table').children()
```

was first finding all ancestor `<table>` elements (in the event of nested `<table>` elements this could be itself a problem) and then finding the `children()` elements, which would be the `<tbody>` elements.

Ordinarily this would still allow the colour to show 'through' the `<tr>` and `<td>` elements, but in this case you've assigned a `background-color` to the `<tr>` elements, which prevents the `<tbody>` background from showing.

So there are two alternatives:

1. Define the `<tbody>` element when composing the HTML, and specify the `background-color` on that `<tbody>` element:

   ```js
       function download_excel(element, a, b, c) {
         $(element).closest('tbody')
           // note that 'limegreen' is used simply for easier
           // visualisation of the change:
           .css("background-color", "limegreen");
       }
   ```

   ```html
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <table>
         <tbody style="background-color: #eaeaea;">
           <tr style="color: rgb(31, 73, 125);">
             <td style="padding-left: 5px;"><a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="download_excel(this,'BL8','ATR','AWFR')">ATR-ADM-BLCMA8-CHN18-03-01-D</a></td>
             <td>14</td>
             <td>0</td>
             <td>56</td>
             <td>56</td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
           </tr>
           <tr style="color: rgb(31, 73, 125);">
             <td style="padding-left: 5px;"><a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="download_excel(this,'BL8','ATR','AWFR')">ATR-ADM-BLCMA8-CHN18-03-01-D</a></td>
             <td>14</td>
             <td>0</td>
             <td>56</td>
             <td>56</td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
           </tr>
           <tr style="color: rgb(31, 73, 125);">
             <td style="padding-left: 5px;"><a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="download_excel(this,'BL8','ATR','AWFR')">ATR-ADM-BLCMA8-CHN18-03-01-D</a></td>
             <td>14</td>
             <td>0</td>
             <td>56</td>
             <td>56</td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
           </tr>
         </tbody>
       </table>
   ```

Note, above, that along with placing the `background-color` on the `<tbody>` element I also removed that property from the `<tr>` elements. In the event of alternative styling specifying the `background-color` you may also need to add the property `background-color: inherit;` on the `<tr>` and/or `<td>` elements.

2. Alternatively you could, instead, navigate from the `element` to the closest `<tbody>` element, then find its children — the `<tr>` elements — and specify their `background-color` as you intended:

   ```js
       function download_excel(element, a, b, c) {
         $(element).closest('tbody')
           .children('tr')
           // note that 'limegreen' is used simply for easier
           // visualisation of the change:
           .css("background-color", "limegreen");
       }
   ```

   ```html
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <table>
         <tr style="color: rgb(31, 73, 125); background-color: #eaeaea;">
           <td style="padding-left: 5px;"><a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="download_excel(this,'BL8','ATR','AWFR')">ATR-ADM-BLCMA8-CHN18-03-01-D</a></td>
           <td>14</td>
           <td>0</td>
           <td>56</td>
           <td>56</td>
           <td></td>
           <td></td>
           <td></td>
           <td></td>
           <td></td>
           <td></td>
           <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr style="color: rgb(31, 73, 125); background-color: #eaeaea;">
           <td style="padding-left: 5px;"><a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="download_excel(this,'BL8','ATR','AWFR')">ATR-ADM-BLCMA8-CHN18-03-01-D</a></td>
           <td>14</td>
           <td>0</td>
           <td>56</td>
           <td>56</td>
           <td></td>
           <td></td>
           <td></td>
           <td></td>
           <td></td>
           <td></td>
           <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr style="color: rgb(31, 73, 125); background-color: #eaeaea;">
           <td style="padding-left: 5px;"><a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="download_excel(this,'BL8','ATR','AWFR')">ATR-ADM-BLCMA8-CHN18-03-01-D</a></td>
           <td>14</td>
           <td>0</td>
           <td>56</td>
           <td>56</td>
           <td></td>
           <td></td>
           <td></td>
           <td></td>
           <td></td>
           <td></td>
           <td></td>
         </tr>
       </table>
   ```

Further, it's worth pointing out that in place of the `style` attributes you should instead use a stylesheet in order to more easily maintain and update the styles of your resulting website which also has the benefit of simplifying the HTML:

```js
function download_excel(element, a, b, c) {
  $(element).closest('tbody')
    // note that 'limegreen' is used simply for easier
    // visualisation of the change:
    .css("background-color", "limegreen");
}
```

```css
tbody {
  background-color: #eaeaea;
}

tr {
  color: rgb(31, 73, 125);
}

td {
  padding-left: 5px;
}

a {
  /* in most cases this would be unnecessary,
     since the default cursor for an <a> element
     is the 'pointer,' so long as an 'href'
     attribute-value is specified: */
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><a onclick="download_excel(this,'BL8','ATR','AWFR')">ATR-ADM-BLCMA8-CHN18-03-01-D</a></td>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>56</td>
      <td>56</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a onclick="download_excel(this,'BL8','ATR','AWFR')">ATR-ADM-BLCMA8-CHN18-03-01-D</a></td>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>56</td>
      <td>56</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a onclick="download_excel(this,'BL8','ATR','AWFR')">ATR-ADM-BLCMA8-CHN18-03-01-D</a></td>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>56</td>
      <td>56</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You're also using obtrusive JavaScript to bind the event-handling for your links, which again requires more care and attention to be paid on updating the document; if, instead, you use JavaScript to bind the event-handlers then maintenance becomes easier:

```
// here we find all <a> elements present within <td> elements,
// and bind the anonymous function of the on() method to the
// 'click' event:
$('td a').on('click', function() {

  // the anonymous function then calls the named function
  // along with its arguments:
  download_excel(this, 'BL8', 'ATR', 'AWFR');
});
```

```js
function download_excel(element, a, b, c) {
  $(element).closest('tbody')
    // note that 'limegreen' is used simply for easier
    // visualisation of the change:
    .css("background-color", "limegreen");
}

$('td a').on('click', function() {
  download_excel(this, 'BL8', 'ATR', 'AWFR');
});
```

```css
tbody {
  background-color: #eaeaea;
}

tr {
  color: rgb(31, 73, 125);
}

td {
  padding-left: 5px;
}

a {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><a>ATR-ADM-BLCMA8-CHN18-03-01-D</a></td>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>56</td>
      <td>56</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a>ATR-ADM-BLCMA8-CHN18-03-01-D</a></td>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>56</td>
      <td>56</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a>ATR-ADM-BLCMA8-CHN18-03-01-D</a></td>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>56</td>
      <td>56</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The above event-binding required the use of an anonymous function to call the named function, since there's no source from which the arguments could be retrieved on the element itself; however if `data-*` custom attributes could be used to retrieve the arguments, then the named function could be used instead:

```
function download_excel() {
  // the element on which the functin is called, the 'this,'
  // is passed automatically via the on() method:
  let element = this,

    // here we retrieve the dataset of the element,
    // the Object in which the custom (data-*) properties
    // and values are kept:
    data = element.dataset,

    // here we retrieve the property-values
    // and assign to variables:
    a = data.a,
    b = data.b,
    c = data.c;

  $(element).closest('tbody')
    // note that 'limegreen' is used simply for easier
    // visualisation of the change:
    .css("background-color", "limegreen");
}

$('td a').on('click', download_excel);
```

```js
function download_excel() {
  let element = this,
    data = element.dataset,
    a = data.a,
    b = data.b,
    c = data.c;

  $(element).closest('tbody')
    .css("background-color", "limegreen");
}

$('td a').on('click', download_excel);
```

```css
tbody {
  background-color: #eaeaea;
}

tr {
  color: rgb(31, 73, 125);
}

td {
  padding-left: 5px;
}

a {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><a data-valuea="BL8" data-valueb="ATR" data-valuec="AWFR">ATR-ADM-BLCMA8-CHN18-03-01-D</a></td>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>56</td>
      <td>56</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a data-a="BL8" data-b="ATR" data-c="AWFR">ATR-ADM-BLCMA8-CHN18-03-01-D</a></td>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>56</td>
      <td>56</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a data-valuea="BL8" data-valueb="ATR" data-valuec="AWFR">ATR-ADM-BLCMA8-CHN18-03-01-D</a></td>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>56</td>
      <td>56</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

In your posted code the arguments to each function call — as well as the link-text itself, so I assume this was for demo purposes — were the same; if this reflects your use-case you can, with ES6, define default values to the event-handling function (though, as noted, I don't believe this is applicable to your real use-case):

```
// Note that here we declare the default-values after declaring the
// event variable which is automatically passed to the function and
// which will always be the first argument:
function download_excel(event, a = "BL8", b = "ATR", c = "AWFR") {
  let element = this;

  // just to confirm my assertion, and to test that it works in
  // your own browser(s):
  console.log(a, b, c);
  $(element).closest('tbody')
    .css("background-color", "limegreen");
}

$('td a').on('click', download_excel);
```

```js
function download_excel(event, a = "BL8", b = "ATR", c = "AWFR") {
  let element = this;
  console.log(a, b, c);
  $(element).closest('tbody')
    .css("background-color", "limegreen");
}

$('td a').on('click', download_excel);
```

```css
tbody {
  background-color: #eaeaea;
}

tr {
  color: rgb(31, 73, 125);
}

td {
  padding-left: 5px;
}

a {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><a>ATR-ADM-BLCMA8-CHN18-03-01-D</a></td>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>56</td>
      <td>56</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a>ATR-ADM-BLCMA8-CHN18-03-01-D</a></td>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>56</td>
      <td>56</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a>ATR-ADM-BLCMA8-CHN18-03-01-D</a></td>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>56</td>
      <td>56</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

It's also worth noting that the above is also simple to implement in native JavaScript (up to, and including, the use of default-values, but as noted: I don't believe that the use of the same arguments is representative):

```
function download_excel() {
  let element = this,
    data = element.dataset,
    a = data.a,
    b = data.b,
    c = data.c;
  console.log(a, b, c);

  element.closest('tbody').style.backgroundColor = 'limegreen';
}

// here we use document.querySelectorAll() to retrieve a
// static nodeList of all <a> elements with a <td> ancestor,
// and iterate over that NodeList using NodeList.prototype.forEach():
document.querySelectorAll('td a').forEach(

  // using an Arrow function:
  // 'anchor' is a reference to the current node of the
  // NodeList over which we're iterating;
  // and here we use the EventTarget.addEventListener()
  // method to bind the download_excel() function as the
  // event-handler of the 'click' function:
  (anchor) => anchor.addEventListener('click', download_excel)
);
```

```js
function download_excel() {
  let element = this,
    data = element.dataset,
    a = data.a,
    b = data.b,
    c = data.c;
  console.log(a, b, c);

  element.closest('tbody').style.backgroundColor = 'limegreen';
}

document.querySelectorAll('td a').forEach(
  (anchor) => anchor.addEventListener('click', download_excel)
);
```

```css
tbody {
  background-color: #eaeaea;
}

tr {
  color: rgb(31, 73, 125);
}

td {
  padding-left: 5px;
}

a {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><a data-a="BL8" data-b="ATR" data-c="AWFR">ATR-ADM-BLCMA8-CHN18-03-01-D</a></td>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>56</td>
      <td>56</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a data-a="BL8" data-b="ATR" data-c="AWFR">ATR-ADM-BLCMA8-CHN18-03-01-D</a></td>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>56</td>
      <td>56</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a data-a="BL8" data-b="ATR" data-c="AWFR">ATR-ADM-BLCMA8-CHN18-03-01-D</a></td>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>56</td>
      <td>56</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

In the event that your (user's) browser may not support arrow functions, this can be rewritten using a typical anonymous function:

```
function download_excel() {
  let element = this,
    data = element.dataset,
    a = data.a,
    b = data.b,
    c = data.c;
  console.log(a, b, c);

  element.closest('tbody').style.backgroundColor = 'limegreen';
}

document.querySelectorAll('td a').forEach(function(anchor){
  anchor.addEventListener('click', download_excel)
});
```

```js
function download_excel() {
  let element = this,
    data = element.dataset,
    a = data.a,
    b = data.b,
    c = data.c;
  console.log(a, b, c);

  element.closest('tbody').style.backgroundColor = 'limegreen';
}

document.querySelectorAll('td a').forEach(function(anchor) {
  anchor.addEventListener('click', download_excel)
});
```

```css
tbody {
  background-color: #eaeaea;
}

tr {
  color: rgb(31, 73, 125);
}

td {
  padding-left: 5px;
}

a {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><a data-a="BL8" data-b="ATR" data-c="AWFR">ATR-ADM-BLCMA8-CHN18-03-01-D</a></td>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>56</td>
      <td>56</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a data-a="BL8" data-b="ATR" data-c="AWFR">ATR-ADM-BLCMA8-CHN18-03-01-D</a></td>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>56</td>
      <td>56</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a data-a="BL8" data-b="ATR" data-c="AWFR">ATR-ADM-BLCMA8-CHN18-03-01-D</a></td>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>56</td>
      <td>56</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

References:

- HTML:

  - [Custom `data-*` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*).
- JavaScript:

  - [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
  - [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
  - [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
  - [`HTMLElement.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset).
- jQuery:

  - [`children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children).
  - [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest).
  - [`on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on).
  - [`parents()`](https://api.jquery.com/parents).
- Relevant other Stack Overflow questions:

  - [Why doesn't table > tr > td work when using the child selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5568859/why-doesnt-table-tr-td-work-when-using-the-child-selector)