# Table not displayed

Tags: javascript, html-table

I want to display table by the way I have in my code below but not displayed in the screen, code is using only html and Javascript

```
<body id="page">
 <center>
    <table id="tables" border="1px" cellspacing="50px" style="margin-top:70px" >
    <script type="text/javascript">
     var row=2;

        for(var j=1;j<=2;j++){          
            $('#tables').append("<tr id='row"+j+"' style='margin-bottom:50px'>");
            for(var k=1;k<=5;k++){
                $("#row"+j).append("<td id='table"+k+"' class='button'  width='150' height='150' onclick='printBill("+k+")' background='images/green.png' align='center'>"+
                                            "<font size='+8'><b>"+k+"</b></font>"+
                                            "<br><font id='clock"+k+"' size='+1'> 0:0:0 </font>"+
                                        "</td>");
                }
            $('#tables').append("<tr id='row"+j+"' style='margin-bottom:50px'>");
        }

    </script>

    </table>
</center>
</body>
```

Can anyone help in finding what's the problem with this code?

Comment: Probably doesn't help that your script is within the table object (so probably isn't being found)... try putting into an onload fired function

Comment: I found your code works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/6332Q/ have you included jQuery?

Comment: offtopic: instead of <center>, you could use `margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;` on the table.

Comment: Plus, you should create only one element with the same id, if you don't want early insanity :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use two typical ways of modifying the document around page loading:

While the html is still loading:

```
<table id="tables">
  <tbody>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.write('<tr>......</tr>');
    </script>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

After the html page is loaded (more specifically when the DOM is ready):

```
<table id="tables">
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){ // see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3
    // the full DOM is ready now, you can start modifying it.
    $('#tables > tbody').append('<tr>......</tr>');
  });
</script>
```

As you can see, I inserted a `tbody` tag between the `table` and its `tr`s: browsers usually create this `tbody` tag, even if your source doesn't contain it. By always adding a `tbody` (or `thead/tfoot` if you wish) you can avoid some potential trouble.

See for example [Can I rely on the implicit creation of the `tbody` tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372243/can-i-rely-on-the-implicit-creation-of-the-tbody-tag) or search for `implicit tbody`.

I cleaned up your code a bit: http://jsfiddle.net/6332Q/1/