# Which DOM elements do browsers automatically insert?

Tags: dom, google-chrome, xpath

I am generating XPaths server-side for use on the client-side, and I was puzzled as why *only* table paths (i.e. content in a `td`) couldn't be found in the DOM.

Turns out, modern browsers (at least Chrome and Firefox) insert a `tbody` tag around table rows upon document loading. See [Why do browsers insert tbody element into table elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938083/why-do-browsers-insert-tbody-element-into-table-elements)

Apart from `tbody`, are there other DOM elements I should be aware of when calculating XPaths server-side?

Comment: If you make sure your server side HTML is _actually_ valid, you don't have any problems.

Comment: @Raynos False. Some elements have optional both start and end tags; your markup can be valid but the elements are still inserted.

Comment: @duri your right, emitting `<tbody>` is valid. I'll correct the statement to say "If you make sure your server side HTML is not ambigious then you won't have any problems"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SGML/HTML4 terminology some other elements can be inferred, even the `head` and the `body` element can be inferred, and HTML5 continues that. So a document like http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/html/test2012011901.html is valid HTML5 although it does neither have `head` nor `body` element and any HTML5 parser is supposed to add them so the DOM tree looks like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Test</h1>
<p>This is a test.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I can't tell you all details about other elements, the above is only an example. Look for details in http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#optional-tags.