# Avoid selecting nested td's. How?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I have this code:

```
$("#widgetstable tr td:nth-child("+column+")").hide();
```

But it selects any td's that happen to be nested inside the selected td's. (And there are a couple.)

I tried `$("#widgetstable > tr > td:nth-child("+column+")").hide();` but it didn't select ANYTHING.

Comment: perhaps you have a `tbody` in your table?

Comment: Nope. Here's the structure at the start: 'code'(<table id="widgetstable" class="sort">
        <tr>
          <td class="draggable">)

Comment: Can you post the HTML you want to apply this to? A jsFiddle would be nice too.

Comment: Remember that nth-child works on index-origin 1, not 0.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot - I know, I already did the +1 math on that.

Comment: @j08691 - Waaaaaay too long and convoluted to try and post here.

Comment: 'twas just a thought. Anyway, I see you have an answer now.

Comment: Then you should narrow the code down to a small example that represents your issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `tbody` is [inserted silently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/938143/16959) when your browser parses your HTML, and the `>` selector means the direct child of the parent.  For the following HTML this selector would work:

```
<style>
   td {
     background-color: blue;
   }
</style>
<table id='widgetstable'>
  <tr>
    <td>Me</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr><td>Not Me</td></tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<script>
  $("#widgetstable > tbody > tr > td").css('background-color', 'red');
</script>
```

[Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uGhgS/)

Comment: Not sure how to mark this as having answered my question... but it did.

Comment: To be safe, I think it would be a good idea to include an explicit `<tbody>` in the HTML. You could also give it an id and simplify the selector to `$("#tbodyId").children("tr").children("td")`.