# Select TRs within table using jquery.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have table within table scenario. When i try to select the trs using 
`$("#table tr");` then it select all the tr from inner tables also.

How can i select tr from outer table only.

Answer (score 5):

Use this instead:

```
$('#table > tr'); // choose direct child tr nodes from table with id 'table'
```

Or

```
$('#table > tbody > tr');
```

If you have `tbody` element.

Here is link to jQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

Comment: I just tested a html without the `tbody` tag in IETester and even the old good IE5.5 (just like all newer browsers) automatically creates the missing `tbody` tag in DOM. So the first selector will always match zero rows. More info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/938083/why-do-browsers-insert-tbody-element-into-table-elements#938143).

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively, it seems like

```
$('table.top > tr');
```

will be sufficient. However, you can't guarantee that it will be. Some browsers implicitly insert a `tbody` element as a parent of all the `tr`s. This is technically required by some versions of the HTML standard. Not all browsers do this, however. For safety, you should probably do something like this:

```
$('table.top > tr, table.top > thead > tr, table.top > tbody > tr');
```

A bit verbose, but more likely to work in more situations.

Comment: @Stano Good catch. I've added a class.

Comment: @Stano [It's not required in HTML5, however](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/tabular-data.html#the-table-element).

Comment: Yes it's not required in HTML, but it's automatically created in DOM. So the `$('table.top > tr');` selector will not find any direct `tr` children. Just tested it in FF and all IEs. **All** browsers insert the tbody element implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

if you have multiple tables in a single page, give them classes so you don't have to go through this every other time..

e.g.

```
$('.mytable > tr')
```

html

```
<table class="mytable">
  <tr>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep:

```
$('#table > tr');
```

But also, if you are making stylistic changes, make sure that you set a base style to all the table rows first (or target the inner tables specifically).

For example, if you execute `$("#table > tr").css("background-color", "orange");` , the inner tables will become orange as well, because by CSS properties they inherit their parent styles.

Set a base color for all table rows first:

```
tr {
background-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two alternatives for [selecting direct children](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors) in the table body with jQuery:

```js
var rows = $('#table > tbody > tr');
```

or

```js
var rows = $('#table').children('tbody').children('tr');
```

The `tbody` element is [created automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938083/why-do-browsers-insert-tbody-element-into-table-elements#938143) in DOM (also in obsolete IE5.5), even when it was not written in HTML.
Using the jQuery's [child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) is more readable and [a bit faster](http://jsperf.com/jquery-s-children-method-vs-child-selector) than [.children() method](http://api.jquery.com/children/).