# Script returns element that not exists on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this function, that returns me path to `el`. However sometimes this function adds element that not exists on page. In this case:

```
<table>
<tr><td></td><tr>
</table>
```

path to td will look like `table > tbody > tr > td`.
Whats the problem with this function?

```
function getDomPath(el) {
        element = el;
        if (!(el instanceof Element)) return;
        var path = [];
        while (el.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE &&  el.id != "jobs") {
            var selector = el.nodeName.toLowerCase();
            if (el.id) {
                selector += '#' + el.id;
            }
            else if(el.className){
                console.log(el.className);
                selector += '.' + el.className;
            }
            else {
                var sib = el, nth = 1, count = 1;
                while (sib.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE && (sib = sib.previousSibling)  && nth++){
                    console.log(Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
                    console.log(el.previousSibling);
                    console.log(el);
                    count += $(el).prevAll().size();
                };
                selector += ":nth-child("+count+")";
            }
            path.unshift(selector);
            el = el.parentNode;
        }
        return path.join(" > ");
    };
```

Comment: I think you should read about optional HTML tags and how forgiving parsers add those to the DOM.

Comment: Mind to point me to some specific article?

Comment: See http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.1 -- the syntax `(CAPTION?, (COL*|COLGROUP*), THEAD?, TFOOT?, TBODY+)` means that the only valid children of a `TABLE` element are `CAPTION`, `COL`, `COLGROUP`, `THEAD`, `TFOOT` and `TBODY`. Also, the '+' after `TBODY` means that this element is **required**. If you put `TR` elements directly inside a `TABLE`, then your markup is invalid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the *problem* is the `tbody` element, you need to know that it's not your function that adds it but the browser itself.
Look at your page using Firebug or the Web Developer tools in chrome.

Take a look at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938083/why-do-browsers-insert-tbody-element-into-table-elements).

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with the function, it correctly uses all the elements that does exist.

A `table` element always has a `tbody` element if there are any rows for it. The browser adds the `tbody` element even if you don't have any tag for it in the markup.

The browser will create complete elements, even if your markup is incomplete or if it has left out optional tags. For example, the browser will create two rows in your table, because you used `<td>` instead of `</td>` when you tried to end the first row. It will implicitly end the first row, start a new row, and implicitly end that too. The elements in  your table will end up just as if you wrote your markup as:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```