# Prevent Html Agility Pack from changing loaded page source

Tags: javascript, html, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I'm having a problem with using `Html Agility Pack` to extract data from websites. The page source that loaded by `Html Agility` is not the same as the source from `View Page Source` menu in browser. Here is the difference I have:

View Page Source:

```
<td>
    <span style="color:#158EF7; font-weight:bold">
        ABCDEF
    </span>
</td>
```

Source returned from `Html Agility`

```
<td>
    <font face="Arial" color="#404040" size="2">
        <span style="color:#158EF7; font-weight:bold">
            ABCDEF
        </span>
    </font>
</td>
```

I don't know why it has this big difference. Maybe because of the javascript code or something else. But I don't care about it, I just want to get the exact source like the one I get from `View Page Source` menu. How can I achieve that? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem too when parsing Google to find out webpages and their position. Exactly as you say the string that I fecthed **DIFFERED** from the page source.

If I remember correctly you send a HTTP-Header which includes an attribute called **User-Agent** read more here -->[WIKIEPEDIA ABOUT USER-AGENTS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent).This tells the site your parsing  what kind of browser you are or if you are a webcrawling robot.

**Problem**
After many hours I saw that I sent an empty string it was set to a default value though, but I didn't know at the time. This in turn made Google believe I was **not sending the HTTP-REQUEST from a browser**, but a mere mechanical spider... AKA web crawler.

**Solution**
**Try and set your user-agent to the same browser as you are using**. That should give you string more like the page source. 
But!!! If they run scripts that change the content on the site accoring to anything they have scripted. That's a whole other story.

Check here for the different user-agent strings --> [User-agent string list](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Browserlist/).

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot. May I ask you one more question? I'm using FireFox. When I click `Inspect Element`, it automatically changes something, like inserting `<tbody>` in the `<table>`. Can I make `Html Agility` do that too?

Comment: Check here it might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/938083/why-do-browsers-insert-tbody-element-into-table-elements