# Python Web Scraping table returns None

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-table

I'm trying to scrape the temperature elements of a table from www.intellicast.com

```
soup =  BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('http://www.intellicast.com/Local/History.aspx?location=USTX0057').read())
for row in soup('table',{'id':'dailyClimate'})[0].tbody('tr'):
  tds=row
  print tds
```

The result:
TypeErrorL 'NoneType' object is not callable

When looking the the page source code i can see

```
<table id = "dailyClimate" class="Container">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="TitlesAvgRecord">
       <td..
    <td>...</td>
```

So I know there is a tbody as well as a tr element.

If I change .tbody('tr') for .tbody('td') I still get an error so I'm assuming I'm assuming the error is somewhere in calling tbody.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your *browser* inserts a `<tbody>` element, but the actual source doesn't have that element:

```html
<table id="dailyClimate" class="Container">
  <tr class="TitlesAvgRecord">
    <td style="padding-left:5px;">Date</td>
    <td>Average<br />Low</td>
    <td>Average<br />High</td>
    <td>Record<br />Low</td>
    <td>Record<br />High</td>
    <td>Average<br />Precipitation</td>
    <td>Average<br />Snow</td>
  </tr>

<!-- etc. -->
```

See [Why do browsers insert tbody element into table elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938083/why-do-browsers-insert-tbody-element-into-table-elements)

You could use the `html5lib` parser instead (using `BeautifulSoup(source, 'html5lib')`), which would *also* insert the element. However, you don't need to search for it, just go straight to the `<tr>` rows:

```
for row in soup.find('table', id='dailyClimate').find_all('tr'):
```

or using a CSS selector:

```
for row in soup.select('table#dailyClimate tr'):
```

You'd normally only select the `tbody` element if there perhaps were more than one or there was a `thead` or `tfooter` element you wanted to exclude.