# Why lxml isn't finding xpath given by Chrome inspector?

Tags: python, google-chrome, xpath, lxml

Here is my code:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nabucco')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
title = tree.xpath('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/th/i')
print(title)
```

Problem: print(title) prints "[]", empty list.  I expect this to print "Nabucco".  The XPath expression is from Chrome inspector "Copy XPath" function.

Why isn't this working?  Is there a disagreement between lxml and Chrome's xpath engine?  Or am I missing something?  I am somewhat new to python, lxml and xpath.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does this xpath fail using lxml in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23900348/why-does-this-xpath-fail-using-lxml-in-python)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because of the `tbody` tag. You see it in the browser since the tag was [inserted by the browser.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938083/why-do-browsers-insert-tbody-element-into-table-elements) `requests` is not a browser and just downloads the page source as is:

Replace:

```
//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/th/i
```

with:

```
//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/table[1]/tr[1]/th/i
```

Comment: Or just use `//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/table[1]//tr[1]/th/i` and cover both cases.  (Replace `/tbody` with `//`.)