# why xpath derived from chrome does not work

Tags: python, google-chrome, xpath, web-scraping

I am trying to scrap data from [web of science](https://apps.webofknowledge.com/WOS_GeneralSearch_input.do?product=WOS&search_mode=GeneralSearch&SID=Q1yAnqE4al4KxALF7RM&preferencesSaved=)

And here is the [specific page](https://apps.webofknowledge.com/full_record.do?product=WOS&search_mode=GeneralSearch&qid=2&SID=Q1yAnqE4al4KxALF7RM&page=1&doc=3&cacheurlFromRightClick=no) I am going to work with.

Below is the code I use for extract the abstract:

```
import lxml
import requests

url = 'https://apps.webofknowledge.com/full_record.do?product=WOS&search_mode=GeneralSearch&qid=2&SID=Q1yAnqE4al4KxALF7RM&page=1&doc=3&cacheurlFromRightClick=no'
s = requests.Session()
d = s.get(url)
soup1 = etree.HTML(d.text)
```

And here is the xpath I got  through the copy xpath in Chrome:

```
//*[@id="records_form"]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[4]/p/text()
```

So I tried to get the abstract like this

```
path = '//*[@id="records_form"]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[4]/p/text()'   
print(soup1.xpath(path))
```

**However, I just hot an empty list!** Then I tried another way to test the xpath.

**Firstly**, I save the specific page as a local html file.

```
with open('1.html','w',encoding='UTF=8') as f:
    f.write(d.text)
f.close()
```

**Then**, open the file

```
s.mount('file://',FileAdapter())
d = s.get('file:///K:/single_paper.html')
soup2 = etree.HTML(d.text)
soup2.xpath('//*[@id="records_form"]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[4]/p/text()')
```

And it gives me the abstract I want! Could anyone tell me why that happens?

**Weired** when I try to do the steps with another page in the saving local file way, it returns an empty list again!

I checked that the xpath given by Chrome is the same for these two pages.

So could anyone tell me what's wrong with my code and how to fix it?

Comment: You could try more specific xpath expression `(//div[@class="block-record-info"])[2]/p/text()`.

Comment: @vold sorry but could you please explain a little bit more? I don't quite get that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browser given full Xpaths are usually [unhelpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23900348/why-does-this-xpath-fail-using-lxml-in-python?rq=1) and you should use relative and clever ones based on attributes (such as id, class, etc) or any identifying features like contains(@href, 'image').

You could try more specific xpath expression: `(//div[@class="block-record-info"])[2]/p/text()` and rewrite your code like this:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

url = 'https://apps.webofknowledge.com/full_record.do?product=WOS&search_mode=GeneralSearch&qid=2&SID=Q1yAnqE4al4KxALF7RM&page=1&doc=3&cacheurlFromRightClick=no'
s = requests.Session()
r = s.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(r.content)
element = tree.xpath('(//div[@class="block-record-info"])[2]/p/text()')
print(element)
```

Output:[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Though it does work in your case, but here if I copy  and run your code, still I get an empty list and `r.status_code` gives `200`. I open the url in Chrome and it  says *Invalid query. Please check that the timespan is within the selected database\'s coverage.*  Do you know what's wrong?

Comment: I tried with another link that I just copy from a very recent search in the database and it works. So maybe it is due to the time difference..

Comment: Now it  gives me the same response:
`Invalid query. Please check that the timespan is within the selected database\'s coverage.`
But if another link works fine it irrelevant.