# Nokogiri not working for advanced XPath search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, xpath, nokogiri

Take a look at this page: http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=AAPL

The XPath

```
(//*[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' snapshot-table2 ')]/tbody/tr/td[text() = 'Index']/following::td)[1]/b
```

should spit out `S&P 500`, and when I try it out in the JavaScript console, it does. However, when I try using Nokogiri with Ruby, it returns an empty array.

Here's the full code:

```
url = "http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=#{ticker}"
data = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
xpath = "(//*[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' snapshot-table2 ')]/tbody/tr/td[text() = '#{datapoint}']/following::td)[1]/b"
data.xpath(xpath)
```

`data.xpath(xpath)` returns `[]`

Any ideas?

Comment: You can't trust the browser to tell you the correct path to a node. Browsers try to present something usable, and resort to all sorts of fix-ups with malformed HTML. That "fixed" HTML is what it will show you. Instead, look at the same HTML that Nokogiri will see when your `open` statement hands off the IO handle. Use `open(url).read` and you'll see the raw HTML as sent by the server, which will give you a better chance to find the right XPath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the response of that page, I don't see a `<tbody>` element.

You mentioned your XPath works in your browser console, this is likely because the browser is injecting the tbody element for rendering purposes, see "[Why do browsers insert tbody element into table elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/938143/689708)" for detail on why this happens.

Try your XPath again without specifying the `<tbody>` node:

```
data.xpath("(//*[contains(@class, 'snapshot-table2')]/tr/td[text() = 'Index']/following::td)[1]/b")
```

You could also use something like this to get the same XPath to work in both the browser and your Ruby code:

```
(//*[contains(@class, 'snapshot-table2')]//tr/td[text() = 'Index']/following::td)[1]/b
```

Comment: The browser adds `tbody` because it's trying to follow the spec. Whether the HTML had `<tbody>` originally isn't important to the browser, but it is to a parser.