# How to create a table using a loop?

Tags: javascript, loops

The individual table rows are giving me a problem. I have created what I want using divs but I need to use a table instead of divs. My table has 220 cells, 10 rows, and 22 columns. Each cell has to have the value of `i` inside the `innerHTML`. Here is similar to what i want using Divs ( although the cell height and width does not have to be set ):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #container{ 
            width:682px; height:310px; 
            background-color:#555; font-size:85%;
            }

            .cell { 
            width:30px; height:30px;
            background-color:#333; color:#ccc;
            float:left; margin-right:1px;
            margin-bottom:1px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <script>
                for( var i = 1; i <= 220; i++ ){
                    document.getElementById( 'container' ).innerHTML += 
                    '<div class="cell">' + i + '</div>'
                }
            </script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8r6619wL/

This is my starting attempt using a table:

```
<script>
    for( var i = 0; i <= 10; i++ )
    {
        document.getElementById( 'table' ).innerHTML +=
        '<tr id = "row' + i + '"><td>...</td></tr>';
    }
</script>
```

But that code somehow dynamically creates a bunch of tbody elements. Thanks for help as I newb

Comment: Use `document.createElement()` instead of `innerHTML` for dynamically inserting elements. `innerHTML` will remove any events attached to the child elements and will have to re-render _every single row element_ all over again each time you parse it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with nested loops - one to add cells to each row and one to add rows to the table. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aaexj7kt/1/)

```
var table = document.createElement('table'), tr, td, row, cell;
for (row = 0; row < 10; row++) {
    tr = document.createElement('tr');
    for (cell = 0; cell < 22; cell++) {
        td = document.createElement('td');
        tr.appendChild(td);
        td.innerHTML = row * 22 + cell + 1;
    }
    table.appendChild(tr);
}
document.getElementById('container').appendChild(table);
```

[Alternatively](http://jsfiddle.net/z6o3y889/2/), you can create an empty row of 22 cells, clone it 10 times, and then add the numbers to the cells.

```
var table = document.createElement('table'),
    tr = document.createElement('tr'),
    cells, i;
for (i = 0; i < 22; i++) { // Create an empty row
    tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
}
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) { // Add 10 copies of it to the table
    table.appendChild(tr.cloneNode(true));
}
cells = table.getElementsByTagName('td'); // get all of the cells
for (i = 0; i < 220; i++) {               // number them
    cells[i].innerHTML = i + 1;
}
document.getElementById('container').appendChild(table);
```

And a [third option](http://jsfiddle.net/p73mbuc0/2/): add the cells in a single loop, making a new row every 22 cells.

```
var table = document.createElement('table'), tr, td, i;
for (i = 0; i < 220; i++) { 
    if (i % 22 == 0) { // every 22nd cell (including the first)
        tr = table.appendChild(document.createElement('tr')); // add a new row
    }
    td = tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
    td.innerHTML = i + 1;
}
document.getElementById('container').appendChild(table);
```

Edit - how I would do this nowadays (2021)... with a helper function of some kind to build dom elements, and using `map`.

```
function make(tag, content) {
  const el = document.createElement(tag);
  content.forEach(c => el.appendChild(c));
  return el;
}

document.getElementById("container").appendChild(make(
    "table", [...Array(10).keys()].map(row => make(
      "tr", [...Array(22).keys()].map(column => make(
        "td", [document.createTextNode(row * 22 + column + 1)]
    ))
  ))
));
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of ways to do this, but one I've found to be helpful is to create a `fragment` then append everything into it. It's fast and limits DOM re-paints/re-flows from a loop.

Take a look at this [jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/sujoqejote/1/edit?html,js,output).

Here's the modified code:

```
function newNode(node, text, styles) {
  node.innerHTML = text;
  node.className = styles;
  return node;
}

var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment(),
  container = document.getElementById("container");

for(var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  var tr = document.createElement("tr");
  var td = newNode(document.createElement("td"), i, "cell");
  tr.appendChild(td);
  fragment.appendChild(tr);
}

container.appendChild(fragment);
```

You can modify whatever you want inside the loop, but this should get you started.

Comment: What about the other tds though?Is it possible to do this: http://jsfiddle.net/8r6619wL/ to the table?

Answer (score 1):

That's because the [DOM](http://css-tricks.com/dom/) magically wraps a `<tbody>` element around stray table rows in your table, [as it is designed to do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/938143/560642). Fortunately, you can rewrite your loop in a way that will add *all* of those table rows at once, rather than one at a time.

The simplest solution to achieve this would be to store a string variable, and concatenate your rows onto that. Then, after you've concatenated your rows together into one string, you can set the `innerHTML` of your table element to that one string like so:

```
<script>
(function() {
    var rows = '';
    for( var i = 0; i <= 10; i++ )
    {
        rows += '<tr id = "row' + i + '"><td>...</td></tr>';
    }
    document.getElementById( 'table' ).innerHTML = rows;
}());
</script>
```

Here's [a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yoLmefq6/) that demonstrates what I've just written. If  you inspect the HTML using your browser's developer tools, you'll notice that one (and only one) `tbody` wraps around *all* of your table rows.

Also, if you're wondering, the odd-looking function which wraps around that code is simply a fancy way of keeping the variables you've created from becoming global (because they don't need to be). See [this blog post](http://sarfraznawaz.wordpress.com/2012/01/26/javascript-self-invoking-functions/) for more details on how that works.

Comment: This helps me move forward, but the end goal is for the table to look like this: http://jsfiddle.net/8r6619wL/. My plan was to loop through the rows first, then inside of each row, loop through each td element. Is this possible to do this and keep I incrementing?

Answer (score 0):

please check this out.
This is a very simple way to create a table using js and HTML

```
<body>
    <table cellspacing="5" >
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Particulate count</td>
                <td>Temperature</td>
                <td>Humidity</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="xxx">

        </tbody>
    </table>

    <script>
        for (var a=0; a < 2; a++) {
            var table1 = document.getElementById('xxx');
            var rowrow =  document.createElement('tr');
        
            for ( i=0; i <1; i++) {
                var cell1  =  document.createElement('td');
                var text1 = document.createTextNode('test1'+a);

                var cell2  =  document.createElement('td');
                var text2 = document.createTextNode('test2'+a);

                var cell3  =  document.createElement('td');
                var text3 = document.createTextNode('test3'+a);

                cell1.appendChild(text1);
                rowrow.appendChild(cell1);

                cell2.appendChild(text2);
                rowrow.appendChild(cell2);

                cell3.appendChild(text3);
                rowrow.appendChild(cell3);
            }
            table1.appendChild(rowrow);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```