# Can't get text values using XPATH in python

Tags: python, html, xpath, request, lxml

I'm trying to parse currencies from [this bank website](http://www.nbu.com/exchange_rates). In code:

```
import requests
import time
import logging
from retrying import retry
from lxml import html

logging.basicConfig(filename='info.log', format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

@retry(wait_fixed=5000)
def fetch_data_from_nb_ved_ru():
try:
    page = requests.get('http://www.nbu.com/exchange_rates')
    #print page.text
    tree = (html.fromstring(page.text))
    #fetched_ved_usd_buy = tree.xpath('//div[@class="exchangeRates"]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[5]')
    fetched_ved_usd_buy = tree.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div//div[7]/div/div/div[1]//text()')
    print fetched_ved_usd_buy
    fetched_ved_usd_sell = str(tree.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[7]/div/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[6]/text()')).strip()
    fetched_ved_eur_buy = str(tree.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[7]/div/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[7]/td[5]/text()')).strip()
    fetched_ved_eur_sell = str(tree.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[7]/div/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[7]/td[6]/text()')).strip()
    fetched_cb_eur = str(tree.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[7]/div/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[7]/td[4]/text()')).strip()
    fetched_cb_rub = str(tree.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[7]/div/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[18]/td[4]/text()')).strip()
    fetched_cb_usd = str(tree.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[7]/div/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[4]/text()')).strip()
except:
    logging.warning("NB VED UZ fetch failed")
    raise IOError("NB VED UZ  fetch failed")
return fetched_ved_usd_buy, fetched_ved_usd_sell, fetched_cb_usd, fetched_ved_eur_buy, fetched_ved_eur_sell,\
    fetched_cb_eur, fetched_cb_rub

while True:
    f = open('values_uzb.txt', 'w')
    ved_usd_buy, ved_usd_sell, cb_usd, ved_eur_buy, ed_eur_sell, cb_eur, cb_rub = fetch_data_from_nb_ved_ru()
               f.write(str(ved_usd_buy)+'\n'+str(ved_usd_sell)+'\n'+str(cb_usd)+'\n'+str(ved_eur_buy)+'\n'+str(ed_eur_sell)+'\n'
        + str(cb_eur)+'\n'+str(cb_rub))

    f.close()
    time.sleep(120)
```

But it always returns empty string, however if I do `print page.text`, i can see that the values are on their's places. 
I got that xpath from firebug. Chrome gives the same xpath.
Tried to construct own xpath
`//div[@class="exchangeRates"]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[5]`
but it happens to be not valid to.

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: Try without the tbody in the xpath.

Comment: Looks like the nbu site is down

Comment: @AnandSKumar, removed tbody, result is the same :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not certain what you are looking for exactly, but this works:

```
tree.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[7]/div/div/div[1]//text()")
```

As for starting with the class `exchangeRates`, I found by using `tree.xpath("//div[@class='exchangeRates']/table")[0].getchildren()` that there is no `tbody` child of `table`, even though browsers say there is. See [this SO question for an explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938083/why-do-browsers-insert-tbody-element-into-table-elements). Removing `tbody` from your original xpath does work. However, the one you chose (`td[5]`) is empty, thus returning `[]`. Try

```
tree.xpath("//div[@class='exchangeRates']/table/tr[5]/td[4]//text()")
# ['706.65']
```

or

```
tree.xpath("//div[@class='exchangeRates']/table/tr[6]/td[5]//text()")
# ['2638.00']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked great! But how did you find the path `"/html/body/div[1]/div[7]/div/div/div[1]//text()"` ?

Comment: Just trial and error. Started with "/html" and added a child one at a time until I found where your first guess stopped working.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this xpath:

```
tree.xpath('//div[@class="exchangeRates"]//tr[NUMBER OF TR]/td[5]/text()')
```

Another thing... I thing if you put this code you will improve your code:

```
trs = tree.xpath('//div[@class="exchangeRates"]//tr')
    for tr in trs:
        currency_code = tr.xpath('./td[7]/text()').strip()

        if currency_code=='USD':
            usd_buy = tr.xpath('./td[5]/text()').strip()
            usd_sell = tr.xpath('./td[6]/text()').strip()
            usd_cb = tr.xpath('./td[4]/text()').strip()
```

And continue with other currency that you need.

It is a quickly code, if you need more details reply please.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following statement, which runs perfectly fine for me.

```
ActualValue = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div/div[2]/div").text
```