# Unable to get text using xpath

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using scrapy to extract text from a td element from this [site](https://web.archive.org/web/20200310105744/https://www.mohfw.gov.in/).

```
response.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/ol/li[2]/strong/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/text()').get()
```

element

```
<td align="'centre" width="83" valign="bottom">Delhi</td>
```

But it is returning blank.

How can I get the text from a tag when align, width are defined?

Comment: Hey Shubham. Is this of help https://stackoverflow.com/a/32252139/10357334

Comment: Removing tbody is giving me the result. Thank you.