# Input not getting appended on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, event-delegation

I'm creating a simple tree structure which holds input field as child. Each child consist of one input field and two buttons. One button is for adding child for the input and another for removing the node. My code is shown in below snippet and it's not working as expected. The problem is that : I can't add more than one child only one child is getting added.

```js
$("#main").on('click', '.add', function() {
  var $td = $(this).parent();
  var $td1 = $('<td>', {
    html: '<input  />      <button class="add">        Add      </button>      <button class="remove">        Remove      </button>'
  });
  console.log($td.children('table').length);
  if ($td.children('table').length)
    $td.children('table').children('tr').append($td1);
  else
    $td.append($('<table>', {
      html: $('<tr>', {
        html: $td1
      })
    }))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="main" style="width:100%;text-align:center">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" />
      <button class="add">
        Add
      </button>
      <button class="remove">
        Remove
      </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The browser parser add a `tbody` so this returns empty matched set: `$td.children('table').children('tr')`. Use `find()` instead `$td.children('table').find('tr')`

Comment: @A.Wolff : yup you are correct , it's working after adding `children('tbody')`

Comment: @A.Wolff : `$td.children('table').find('tr')` this will be much better and while appending I can use `eq(0)` to avoid nested `tr`. please add it as answer.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browser parser on all modern browsers (AFAIK?!) add `TBODY` element. For more details, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/938143/1414562).

In your case, this would make `$td.children('table').children('tr')` returning empty matched set, because `children()` is only targeting direct descendant (one level).

You could use instead `find()` method, matching any descendant:

```
$td.children('table').find('tr').append($td1);
```