# Trying to get table rows with Scrapy xpath

Tags: xpath, scrapy

[image]

I have some html that looks like the screenshot. I want to get the table rows. I have:

```
for table_row in response.selector.xpath("//*[@id = 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_CaseDetailParties1_gvParties']"):
    print table_row
```

In the command line I tried:

```
>>> table_row
Out[5]: <Selector xpath="//*[@id = 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_CaseDetailParties1_gvParties']" data=u'<table class="ParamText" cellspacing="0"'>
>>> table_row.xpath('/tbody')
Out[6]: []
>>> table_row.xpath('//tbody')
Out[7]: []
```

Why am I unable to select the tbody?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*`tbody` is [generated by the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938083/why-do-browsers-insert-tbody-element-into-table-elements)*, you don't get it with Scrapy downloader. Just get straight to the `tr` elements:

```
table_row.xpath('.//tr')
```

Comment: Wow, I thought I was going crazy. Thank you!

Comment: If I can, I have a follow up: There are multiple nested tables inside the tr elements in this table.How can I get just the children tr's in other words, table_row.xpath('//tbody/tr') if tbody existed

Comment: @user61629 ah, you should then filter top level `tr`s, if I understand you correctly, e.g. `table_row.xpath('./tr')`..

Comment: Yes thats it. Thank you very much!